# Fastest way to add a prefix to all array keys?

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation, key, prefix

What is the fastest way to prepend a string to all keys in a flat array?

Input

```
$array = array(
 '1' => 'val1',
 '2' => 'val2',
);
```

Needed output:

```
$array = array(
  'prefix1' => 'val1',
  'prefix2' => 'val2',
);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've found that PHPBench is not a very good source for non-trivial benchmarks. So unless your actually interested in running `for(....);` it's not going to correctly show which syntax will be faster. I've put together a simple benchmark to show that foreach is actually the fastest when your use both the key and value during the iteration.

It's very important to actually force PHP to read the values from a loop iteration, or else it'll do its best to optimize them out. In the example below I use the `doNothing` function to force PHP to calculate the key and value each time. Using doNothing will cause an overhead to be applied to each loop, but it will be the same for each loop since the number of calls will be the same.

I wasn't really that surprised that `foreach` came out on top since it's the language construct for iterating a dictionary.

```
$array = range( 0, 1000000 );

function doNothing( $value, $key ) {;}

$t1_start = microtime(true);
foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
    doNothing( $value, $key );
}
$t1_end = microtime(true);

$t2_start = microtime(true);
$array_size = count( $array );
for( $key = 0; $key < $array_size; $key++ ) {
    doNothing( $array[$key], $key );
}
$t2_end = microtime(true);

    //suggestion from PHPBench as the "fastest" way to iterate an array
$t3_start = microtime(true);
$key = array_keys($array);
$size = sizeOf($key);
for( $i=0; $i < $size; $i++ ) {
    doNothing( $key[$i], $array[$key[$i]] );
}
$t3_end = microtime(true);

$t4_start = microtime(true);
array_walk( $array, "doNothing" );
$t4_end = microtime(true);

print
    "Test 1 ".($t1_end - $t1_start)."\n". //Test 1 0.342370986938
    "Test 2 ".($t2_end - $t2_start)."\n". //Test 2 0.369848966599
    "Test 3 ".($t3_end - $t3_start)."\n". //Test 3 0.78616809845
    "Test 4 ".($t4_end - $t4_start)."\n"; //Test 4 0.542922019958
```

Edit: I'm using PHP 5.3 on 64-bit Mac OSX 10.6

Comment: It's a bit weird because I'm getting values 10 times lower: `0.043029069900513`. Do you know why that might be happening? It's PHP 5.4.3. And if I run this for just a single `foreach` and not my a bit longer script then it's: `6.4849853515625E-5`

Comment: They seem to be in the right ballpark for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/b1gHRC. Foreach is still the clear winner.

Comment: Yes, foreach is the winner but I wonder why this website shows `0.0497624` and my website, with exactly the same script shows `0.0000871`.

Comment: Sounds like you had a typo that caused it not to run correctly.

Comment: Or maybe you have a different hosting with different specifications..?

Comment: I find this to be an inappropriate post for this page (I'll go as far as to say that it is Not An Answer) because it makes no attempt to benchmark actual techniques that will prepend a string to the keys of an array.  This is probably the correct answer to a different question such as: [Performance of FOR vs FOREACH in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3430194/2943403) or [Is using native PHP functionality faster than doing the same thing in PHP loops? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25672638/2943403) or any one of the other 30-odd pages on iteration in PHP.

Answer (score 75):

Could do this in one long line I presume:

```
$prefix = "prefix";
$array = array_combine(
    array_map(
        function($k) use ($prefix) {return $prefix . $k; }, 
        array_keys($array)
     ),
    $array
);
```

Or -- as [Sabrina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1535357/sabrina) points out [in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68554869/367456) -- using an arrow function syntax which is available from php7.4+.

There's probably dozens of ways to do this though:

```php
$prefix = "prefix";
foreach ($array as $k => $v)
{
    $array[$prefix . $k] = $v;
    unset($array[$k]);
}
```

---

Now historically for versions of PHP prior to 5.3:

```php
$prefix = "prefix";
$array = KeyPrefixer::prefix($array, $prefix);

class KeyPrefixer
{
    private $prefix;
    public function __construct($prefix) {
        $this->prefix = (string)$prefix;       
    }

    public static function prefix(array $array, $prefix)
    {
        $prefixer = new KeyPrefixer($prefix);
        return $prefixer->mapArray($array);
    }

    public function mapArray(array $array)
    {
        return array_combine(
            array_map(array($this, 'mapKey', array_keys($array)),
            $array
        );
    }

    public function mapKey($key) {
        return $this->prefix . (string)$key;
    }
}
```

which was originally without the `$prefix` as parameter and with a call to `create_function()`, which should not be used due to high in-own-foot-shooting-potential. Only for reference:

```php
$array = array_combine(
    array_map(create_function('$k', 'return "prefix$k";'), array_keys($array)),
    $array
);
```

Direct compare with arrow function:

```php
$array = array_combine(
    array_map(fn($k) => "prefix$k", array_keys($array)),
    $array
);
```

Comment: No need to set `array_values()` for `array_map()` as 2nd arg. If you just throw the array in it, it will use the value anyway.

Answer (score 7):

```
function keyprefix($keyprefix, Array $array) {

    foreach($array as $k=>$v){
        $array[$keyprefix.$k] = $v;
        unset($array[$k]);
    }

    return $array; 
}
```

Using `array_flip` will not preserve empty or null values.
Additional code could be added in the unlikely event that the prefixed key already exists.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to write [@Lode's first snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2609278/2943403) using arrow function syntax which is available from php7.4+:

```
function prefixArrayKeys($array, $prefix) {
    return array_combine(
        array_map(fn($k) => $prefix . $k, array_keys($array)),
        $array
    );
}
```

Tests:

```php
function testPrefixArrayKeys() {
    // Test case 1
    $array = ['name' => 'John', 'age' => 30];
    assert(prefixArrayKeys($array, 'prefix_') == ['prefix_name' => 'John', 'prefix_age' => 30]);
    
    // Test case 2
    $array = ['city' => 'New York'];
    assert(prefixArrayKeys($array, '') == ['city' => 'New York']);
    
    // Test case 3
    $array = [];
    assert(prefixArrayKeys($array, 'prefix_') == []);
    
    // Test case 4
    $array = [1 => 'One', 2 => 'Two'];
    assert(prefixArrayKeys($array, 'prefix_') == ['prefix_1' => 'One', 'prefix_2' => 'Two']);
    
    echo 'All test cases passed!';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use for loop you can do:

```
// function called by array_walk to change the $value  in $key=>$value.
function myfunction(&$value,$key) {
    $value="prefix$value";
}

$keys = array_keys($array);  // extract just the keys.
array_walk($keys,"myfunction"); // modify each key by adding a prefix.
$a = array_combine($keys,array_values($array)); // combine new keys with old values.
```

I don't think this will be more efficient than the `for` loop. I guess array_walk will internally use a loop and there is also the function call overhead here.

Comment: while working, that's incredibly slow compared to a for loop isn't it?

Comment: You should not use by-reference. This is actually slower and more intensive than just passing and return it. Cant find docs real quick atm.

Answer (score 2):

```
function array_key_prefix_suffix(&$array,$prefix='',$suffix=''){
        $key_array = array_keys($array);
        $key_string = $prefix.implode($suffix.','.$prefix,$key_array).$suffix;
        $key_array = explode(',', $key_string);
        $array = array_combine($key_array, $array);
    }
```

This is implemented and working very well

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do achieve is with array_flip()

```
<?php 
    $data = array_flip($data);
    foreach($data as $key => &$val) { $val = "prefix" . $val; }
    $data = array_flip($data);
```

Comment: bad option if you have identical values in array

Answer (score 0):

I would create a completely new array, and create your new keys. 
That has to be faster than unsetting all unwanted keys;

```
$prefixed_array = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $prefixed_array[ $prefix . $key] = $value;
}
```

And if you want to do any other "affix"'s

```
function array_affix_keys($affix, Array $array, $type = 'prefix', $options = array()){

    $affixed_array = array();

    if($type =='prefix'){
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {$affixed_array[ $affix . $key] = $value;}
        return $affixed_array;
    }
    if($type =='suffix'){
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {$affixed_array[$key . $affix ] = $value;}
        return $affixed_array;
    }
    if($type =='circumfix'){

        if(is_array($affix) && count($affix) == 2){

            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                $affixed_array[ $affix[0] . $key . $affix[1] ] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $affixed_array;
    }
    if($type == 'simulfix' && isset($options['phonemes'])){
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) { $affixed_array[ str_replace($options['phonemes'], $affix, $key) ] = $value;}
        return $affixed_array;
    }
    return $array;
}


$prefixed = array_affix_keys('prefix_', $array);
$prefixed = array_affix_keys('prefix_', $array, 'prefix');

$suffixed = array_affix_keys('_suffix', $array, 'suffix');
$circumfixed = array_affix_keys(array('prefix', 'suffix'), $array, 'circumfix');
$simulfix = array_affix_keys('replace', $array, 'simulfix', array('phonemes' => 'find'));
```

Comment: This implementation of `circumfix` is wrong. Circumfix has different ending than the start, e.g. `per(...)kan`. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumfix)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fast, one-liner solution (supported on PHP 4+) to add a prefix and/or suffix using implode / explode:

```
$array = range(0, 1000000);
$delimiter = '-';
$prefix = 'string';
$suffix = '';

$result = array_combine(explode($delimiter, $prefix . implode($suffix . $delimiter . $prefix, array_keys($array)) . $suffix), $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update 2024-03-28:

Very much to my surprise, using `substr_replace()` inside of `array_combine()` (slightly) outperforms `foreach()` in roughly half of the tests  that I performed. This would be my preferred array key prefixer! It might not be intuitive, but it is concise, functional-style, doesn't declare temporary or result variables, and has no iterated user-defined functions. ([See the full test results for different versions](https://3v4l.org/jfHCR))

```
function substrReplaceAndCombinePrefix($array, $prefix = 'prefix') {
    return array_combine(
               substr_replace(array_keys($array), $prefix, 0, 0),
               $array
           );
}
```

---

Earlier answer:

What isn't surprising is that a classic `foreach()` loop is the best performer.  It also happens to be the most concise script.  If your code styling preference doesn't demand functional syntax, then this is probably the best approach.  That said, if your input volume is significantly large, it will be a good idea to benchmark your actual data if performance is a high priority.

What is surprising (to me anyway), is that calling three specific native functions (`array_combine()`, `array_map()`, `array_keys()`) can outperform two specific native functions (`array_reduce()`, `array_keys()`) and even one native function (`array_walk()`)!

`array_walk()` isn't horrifically slow, but `array_reduce()` suffers wicked performance drag.

The following benchmarks are the average of 20 calls of the technique upon arrays with 5000 elements. ([Benchmark Script](https://3v4l.org/j9Reg))

1. `foreach()`: (PHP8.2.5 exec time: **0.36159753799438**)

   ```
   $result = [];
   foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
       $result[$prefix . $k] = $v;
   }
   ```
2. `array_combine()`,`array_map()`,`array_keys()`:  (PHP8.2.5 exec time: **0.52124261856079**)

   ```
   $result = array_combine(
       array_map(
           fn($k) => $prefix . $k,
           array_keys($array)
       ),
       $array
   );
   ```
3. `array_walk()`:  (PHP8.2.5 exec time: **0.77606439590454**)

   ```
   $result = [];
   array_walk(
       $array,
       function($v, $k, $prefix) use (&$result) {
           $result[$prefix . $k] = $v;
       },
       $prefix
   );
   ```
4. `array_reduce()`,`array_keys()`:  (PHP8.2.5 exec time: **49.715828895569**)

   ```
   $result = array_reduce(
       array_keys($array),
       function($res, $k) use ($array, $prefix) {
           $res[$prefix . $k] = $array[$k];
           return $res;
       },
       []
   );
   ```

   Using arrow function syntax with `array_reduce()` does not appear to improve performance.

   ```
   $result = array_reduce(
       array_keys($array),
       fn($result, $k) => $result + [$prefix . $k => $array[$k]],
       []
   );
   ```
5. generator: (PHP8.2.5 exec time: **0.58324337005615**)

   ```
   function generator($array, $prefix) {
       foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
           yield $prefix . $k => $v;
       }
   }
   $result = iterator_to_array(generator($array, $prefix));
   ```

Answer (score -1):

I figured out one-line solution:

```
array_walk($array, create_function('$value, &$key', '$key = "prefix" . $key;'));
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The keys are not changed. It's the same as I've been trying to do for the better part of an hour: http://codepad.org/h88Is8ug