# Best way to return the first repeated element of array

Tags: php, arrays

This is an interview question:

**What is the best way to return the first repeated element out of the array of integers?**

Example:

Given an array `[12, 46, 244, 0, 12, 83, 48, 98, 233, 83, 26, 91, 119, 148, 98]`.

The return value in this case is `12`.

How can this be done?

Comment: What's the question? Certainly you don't mean `return 12;` or `return $array[0];`

Comment: kindly view the question now... hope u will clear

Comment: Actually is there any algorithm to find this?

Comment: function firstDuplicate($a) {
    $array = [];
    foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($array[$value]))
            return $value;
        else
            $array[$value]=true; 
    }
    return -1;
}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i think that if you look of performance, foreach loop is the [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php)

```
# temp array
$array_help = array();

# run over the array
foreach ($array as $val) {

    if (isset($array_help[$val]))
     # found if is set already !
        return $val;

    else
       # its the first time this value appear
       $array_help[$val] = 1;
}
```

Comment: good answer, the only thing I don't like is the fact that you used the "1" value instead of using array values directly

Answer (score 9):

This will give you all the duplicate values and their original positions:

```
$diff = array_diff_assoc($array, array_unique($array));
var_dump($diff);
```

result:

```
array(3) { 
  [4]=> int(12) 
  [9]=> int(83)
  [14]=> int(98) 
}
```

Comment: I agree though that if you only need the first one some other solutions here using foreach are faster.

Comment: This is by far the best solution I've seen

Answer (score 3):

```
function findDuplicate ($array) {
  while (($item = array_shift($array)) !== null) {
    if (in_array($item, $array)) return $item;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to remove all the duplicate values, then iterate over the original and resulting arrays and return the first value that doesn't appear in the resulting array.  Something like this:

```
$arr = array(12, 46, 244, 0, 12, 83, 48, 98, 233, 83, 26, 91, 119, 148, 98);

function first_dupe($arr) {
    $res = array_unique($arr);

    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        if ($res[$key] !== $val)
            return $val;
    }
}

echo first_dupe($arr);
```

**Working demo: http://codepad.org/atFMrhLW.**

Answer (score 2):

```
$arrs = array(12, 46, 244, 0, 12, 83, 48, 98, 233, 83, 26, 91, 119, 148, 98);

// or a associate array like as $arrs = array('a'=>12, 'b'=>46, 'c'=>244, 'd'=>0, 'e'=>12, 'f'=>83, 'g'=>48, 'h'=>98, 'i'=>233, 'j'=>83, 'k'=>26, 'l'=>91, 'm'=>119, 'n'=>148, 'o'=>98);

$data = "12, 46, 244, 0, 12, 83, 48, 98, 233, 83, 26, 91, 119, 148, 98";

static $repeat  = '';

foreach($arrs as $arr){

   if (substr_count($data,$arr)>1) {

     $repeat = $arr;
     break; 
  }

}

if ($repeat) echo 'The first repeated element out of the array of integers is '.$repeat;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$testData = array(46, 12, 244, 0, 12, 83, 48, 98, 233, 83, 26, 91, 119, 148, 98);

function repeated($val) {
    return $val > 1;
}

$firstRepeatedElement = array_shift(array_keys(array_filter(array_count_values($testData),'repeated')));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFirstRepetition($array) {
    $prev = array();
    foreach($array as $value) {

        if (in_array($value, $prev)) {
            return $value;
        }

        $prev[] = $value;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/ybfUgJRJ).

Answer (score 0):

a loopless solution using recursion . I think it will be fastest but take more memory.  Fast because size of array keep on decreasing as we move ahead hence less workload on cpu.

```
 $data = array(46, 12, 244, 0, 12, 83, 48, 98, 233, 83, 26, 91, 119, 148, 98);


    function find(&$input)
    {
    $current = array_shift($input);
    if(in_array($current,$input))
    {
    return $current;
    }
    return find($input);
    }

    echo find($data);
```

Comment: Remember that function calls are slooooooooooow in PHP.

Comment: @thereformhere everything comes down to function in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrs = array(12, 46, 244, 0, 12, 83, 48, 98, 233, 83, 26, 91, 119, 148, 98);

static $repeat  = '';

foreach($arrs as $arr) {

   if ((count(array_keys($arrs,$arr))) > 1) {

        $repeat = $arr;
        break;

   }

}

if ($repeat) echo 'The first repeated element out of the array of integers is '.$repeat;


//This solution is working for associate array too, for example:

// $arrs = array('a'=>12, 'b'=>46, 'c'=>244, 'd'=>0, 'e'=>12, 'f'=>83, 'g'=>48, 'h'=>98, 'i'=>233, 'j'=>83, 'k'=>26, 'l'=>91, 'm'=>119, 'n'=>148, 'o'=>98);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(12, 46, 46, 0, 18, 83, 48, 98, 233, 83, 26, 91, 119, 148, 98);
$count_array = array_count_values($array);
foreach($count_array as $key=>$value)
{
    if($value>=2)
    {
       echo $key;
       break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(12, 46, 244, 0, 12, 83, 48, 98, 233, 83, 26, 91, 119, 148, 98);
$arrHelp = array();
foreach($arr as $int) {
    if (in_array($int, $arrHelp)) {
        echo $int;
        break;
    }
    else {
        array_push($arrHelp, $int);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        here N is size of array and A is array,
        step1:add N to index of the value
        step2:traverse the array and find the first number which has frequency 
              greater than 1 break there.

O(n) with O(1) size complexity!

                for(int i=0;i<N;++i)
                        A[A[i]%N]+=N;

                    int val,freq;
                    for(int i=0;i<N;++i)
                    {
                        val=A[i]%N;
                        freq=A[val]%N;
                        if(freq>1)
                        {
                            cout<<val;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you could use array_count_values() function to fetch that.

```
    $arr = array(12, 46, 244, 0, 12, 83, 48, 98, 233, 83, 26, 91, 119, 148, 98);
    $freq_arr = array_count_values($arr);

    echo $freq_arr[0];
```

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) on PHP Manual.