# need help in mutidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Good evening my helpers!
I have a multidimensional array $data like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => thunderteszt
[1] => orevikod
[2] => 5400
[3] => 6
)
Array
(
[0] => bakterhaz1982
[1] => $s$w$0ffТΉЏИÐΞЯ
[2] => 5540
[3] => 3
)
Array
(
[0] => bakterhaz1982
[1] => $s$w$0ffТΉЏИÐΞЯ
[2] => 5570
[3] => 2
)
Array
(
[0] => bakterhaz1982
[1] => $s$w$0ffТΉЏИÐΞЯ
[2] => 5740
[3] => 1
)
Array
(
[0] => thunderteszt
[1] => orevikod
[2] => 5840
[3] => 5
)
Array
(
[0] => thunderteszt
[1] => orevikod
[2] => 5890
[3] => 4
)
```

You can see I have arrays with repeated nick in row[1] ($s$w$0ffТΉЏИÐΞЯ).
I will pick up the lowest value (row[2]) from the repeated arrays.

Therafter I will make a new array from the picked values and I will see only the following:

```
Array
(
[0] => thunderteszt
[1] => orevikod
[2] => 5400
[3] => 6
)
Array
(
[0] => bakterhaz1982
[1] => $s$w$0ffТΉЏИÐΞЯ
[2] => 5540
[3] => 3
)
```

edit:
I forgot to say: the array already mutisorted by score(row 2) then by nick (row 1)

edit2:
my code sample is the following:

edit3:
Sorry for caps lock in original question :(

```
function pts_panel_on($aseco) {

global $pts;

$maniapos = -1;   
$linkmaniapos = -0.2;
$linkmaniapos2 = -0;
$xml = '<manialinks><manialink id="40400">';
$xml .= '<frame posn="48.2 15 0">';
if (empty($pts->finish)) return true;

$beerok=array();

foreach($pts->finish as $key=>$row){   
$becenev[$key] = $row['nick'];  
$ido[$key] = $row['score']; 
} 

array_multisort($ido, SORT_ASC, $becenev, SORT_ASC, $pts->finish );
foreach($pts->finish as $data){
print_r(array_values($data));
$rpointinc++;
$linkmaniapos =  ($linkmaniapos - 3) ;
$linkmaniapos2 =  ($linkmaniapos2 - 3) ;
$maniapos =  ($maniapos - 3) ;

if ($rpointinc <= 10) { 

$xml .= '<format textsize="1"/><label posn="-19.3 ' . $linkmaniapos. ' 
1.5" sizen="30 3 2" scale="0.3" style="TextRaceChrono" halign="center" 
text="$s$0f0'.$rpointinc .' "/>';
$xml .= '<format textsize="1"/><label posn="-27.5 ' . $linkmaniapos . ' 1.5" 
sizen="30 3 2" halign="left" scale="0.3" style="TextRaceChrono" 
text="$s$fff'.formatTime($data['score']).' "/>';   
$xml .= '<format textsize="1.7"/><label posn="-16.5 ' . $linkmaniapos . ' 
1.6" sizen="12 3 2" halign="left" text="$000' . $data['nick'] . ' "/>';

$xml .= '<quad sizen="4 3" posn="-19.6 ' . $maniapos . ' 1"  valign="center" 
halign="center" style="Bgs1InRace" substyle="NavButton" />';
$xml .= '<quad sizen="6.2 3" posn="-24.9 ' . $maniapos . ' 1"  
valign="center" halign="center" style="Bgs1InRace" substyle="NavButton" />';
$xml .= '<quad sizen="17 3" posn="-17.4 ' . $maniapos . ' 1.1"  
valign="center" halign="left" style="Bgs1InRace" substyle="NavButton"/>';
}

}
$xml .= '</frame>';
$xml .= '</manialink></manialinks>';
foreach ($pts->Players as $data2) {
$aseco->client->query("SendDisplayManialinkPageToLogin", $data2['login'], 
$xml, 0, false);
}
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Code sample edited im my question. maybe help for You.

Comment: Unfortunately no... I can't understand the code, it is not well formatted nor documented.

Comment: my multi array already sorted by score, and by name.

Comment: i will remove the repeated arrays, or create a new array, but in the new array i will see only the login names with the lowest scores

Comment: From your example, your array is not sorted by name (row[0])

Comment: i'm so sorry its true, it's sorted by nickname and score

Comment: my question updated

Comment: i will make like this, but it's only for integer values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065703/best-way-to-return-the-first-repeated-element-of-array

Comment: viewed 35 times and no one can help? :(

Comment: Because you showed no efforts. [Ask]

Comment: i'm very new here. what You think, better ask another forum? I can't understand this NO EFFORT. I already have a working code, just not perfect. Need reach any level for asking? or whats wrong? NO EFFORTS.... lol...

Comment: I can not help others, I'm level1 in php. How reach levels?