# In PHP foreach generate an array and return it will cause CPU utilization increasing

Tags: php, performance, foreach

I have a source array, in foreach() loop a new array will be generated based on some field of the source array. And finally the function will return the new array.

```
function get_role_info() {
    $source_array = array(
        'role1' => array(
            'name' => 'Eric',
            'age' => '30',
            'gender' => 'male'            
        ),
        'role2' => array(
            'name' => 'Emily',
            'age' => '27',
            'gender' => 'female'
        )
        ......
    );
    foreach ($source_array as $role_name => $role) {       
        $new_info= array();    
        $new_info['role-name'] = $role_name; 
        $new_storage['user-name'] = $role['name'];
        ...... //other filters

        $newinfo[] = $new_info;    
    }    

    return $newinfo;
}
```

The calling of this function will cause CPU utilization increase a lot.
If I change foreach to a for loop

```
for ($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++) {
    ....... // same logic to filter fields
}
```

The CPU utilization will go down...
I'm not sure what's the differences between these 2?
If I just print the new array and not return it, the CPU will not grow high either.
Does anyone have some clue about it? Thx.

Answer (score 4):

Each `foreach` iteration returns a copy of the actual data you have in the array, if it is a large array and/or multidimensional, you are operating on copied data and then returning `$newInfo` and thats why the CPU doesn't agree with you in this case I guess.

`for` loop on the other hand is just looping until you tell it to stop (until `$i < $cnt` for example), it doesn't care what changes you're applying where, and it certainly doesn't copy anything over to anywhere. It just loops.

Also, http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php recommends you to `unset($source_array)` before you continue with your script (as it is copied, and you have two arrays in memory now)

*just found this*:
Read more: [Performance of FOR vs FOREACH in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php)