# Create array from an array in the same array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [LogDate] => Wed , Nov 14 , 2012
        [LogIDs] => 1,2
        [LogContents] => Hello!,Hello 2...
        [LogAuthors] => yan,yan
        [LogTimes] => 12:00 AM,12:00 AM
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [LogDate] => Thu , Nov 15 , 2012
        [LogIDs] => 3,4
        [LogContents] => Hello world...,Hi world...
        [LogAuthors] => jonathan,jonathan
        [LogTimes] => 12:00 AM,12:00 AM
    )
```

)

And I want to restructure it to look like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [LogDate] => Wed , Nov 14 , 2012
        [0] => Array
            (
                [LogIDs] => 1
                [LogContents] => Hello!
                [LogAuthors] => yan
                [LogTimes] => 12:00 AM
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [LogIDs] => 2
                [LogContents] => Hello 2...
                [LogAuthors] => yan
                [LogTimes] => 12:00 AM
            )
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [LogDate] => Thu , Nov 15 , 2012
        [0] => Array
            (
                [LogIDs] => 3
                [LogContents] => Hello world...
                [LogAuthors] => jonathan,jonathan
                [LogTimes] => 12:00 AM
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [LogIDs] => 4
                [LogContents] => Hi world...
                [LogAuthors] => jonathan
                [LogTimes] => 12:00 AM
            )
    )
```

)

Is this possible?

I have tried like(updated version, working):

```
$result =   $this->mymodel->fetch_logs(1, 5, 0);
    $new_array = array();
    $inner_array = array();
    $kounter = 0;
    foreach($result as $row){

        $new_array[] = array(
        'LogDate' => $row['LogDate'],           
        );

        $log_ids = explode(',',$row['LogIDs']);
        $log_contents = explode(',',$row['LogContents']);
        $log_authors = explode(',',$row['LogAuthors']);
        $log_times = explode(',',$row['LogTimes']);

        $counter = count($log_ids);

        for($i=0; $i<$counter; $i++){
            $inner_array = array(
                'LogID' => $log_ids[$i],
                'LogContent' => $log_contents[$i],
                'LogAuthor' => $log_authors[$i],
                'LogTime' => $log_times[$i]
            );                              
            //array_push($new_array, $inner_array); 
            $new_array[$kounter][$i] = $inner_array;                                    
        }   
        $kounter++;
    }
```

But the inner_array I pushed goes higher level than [LogDate]. They should be on same level sa LogDate. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go, the code to do what you want. Keep in mind that the code does expect an equal number of values for each part. So if you have two id's, you also need to values in the content, authers and times part. Also the content can not have a comma in it, besides from the seperator.

```
<pre>
<?php
$ar[0] = ['LogDate'=>'Wed , Nov 14 , 2012', 'LogIDs' => '1,2', 'LogContents' => 'Hello!,Hello 2...', 'LogAuthors' => 'yan,yan', 'LogTimes' => '12:00 AM,12:00 AM'];
$ar[1] = ['LogDate'=>'Thu , Nov 15 , 2012', 'LogIDs' => '3,4', 'LogContents' => 'Hello world...,Hi world...', 'LogAuthors' => 'jonathan,jonathan', 'LogTimes' => '12:00 AM,12:00 AM'];
print_r($ar);

$newar = [];
foreach($ar as $key=>$val) {
    $newar[$key] = [];
    $date = $val['LogDate'];
    $arIds = explode(',', $val['LogIDs']);
    $arContents = explode(',', $val['LogContents']);
    $arAuthors = explode(',', $val['LogAuthors']);
    $arTimes = explode(',', $val['LogTimes']);

    $newar[$key]['LogDate'] = $date;
    foreach($arIds as $k=>$v) {
      $tar = [];
      $tar['LogIDs'] = $v;
      $tar['LogContents'] = $arContents[$k];
      $tar['LogAuthors'] = $arAuthors[$k];
      $tar['LogTimes'] = $arTimes[$k];

      $newar[$key][] = $tar;
    }
}

print_r($newar);


?>
</pre>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [LogDate] => Wed , Nov 14 , 2012
            [LogIDs] => 1,2
            [LogContents] => Hello!,Hello 2...
            [LogAuthors] => yan,yan
            [LogTimes] => 12:00 AM,12:00 AM
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [LogDate] => Thu , Nov 15 , 2012
            [LogIDs] => 3,4
            [LogContents] => Hello world...,Hi world...
            [LogAuthors] => jonathan,jonathan
            [LogTimes] => 12:00 AM,12:00 AM
        )
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [LogDate] => Wed , Nov 14 , 2012
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LogIDs] => 1
                    [LogContents] => Hello!
                    [LogAuthors] => yan
                    [LogTimes] => 12:00 AM
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [LogIDs] => 2
                    [LogContents] => Hello 2...
                    [LogAuthors] => yan
                    [LogTimes] => 12:00 AM
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [LogDate] => Thu , Nov 15 , 2012
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LogIDs] => 3
                    [LogContents] => Hello world...
                    [LogAuthors] => jonathan
                    [LogTimes] => 12:00 AM
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [LogIDs] => 4
                    [LogContents] => Hi world...
                    [LogAuthors] => jonathan
                    [LogTimes] => 12:00 AM
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have also updated my code above and after some experiments, it finally work. But I think my code is so elementary. Which do you think is much better in handling hundreds of data? I'll mark your answer as accepted, but I'll need to study your codes. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks. With hundreds of data the differences will be practically none. There are two main differences in our code. You use a `for` loop and I use `foreach`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php goes into whats faster. Then you create the array in one statement and I change the value per key. In my test on 100000 records your way was a few MS faster

Comment: Thanks for the response. That clears things up, specially the link you provided.