# Which loop is better in performance - foreach or for?

Tags: php, optimization, for-loop, foreach

I was Eager about which looping technique is considered best in performance among `foreach` and `for`? and we can also optimize the script by finding the best practice for looping.

Comment: Measure and see for yourself: but remember that `foreach` is specifically for arrays and iterable objects, while `for` is more general purpose. You might also want to look at `while` loops

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Also use echo instead of print. echo doesn't return a value so will save you precious CPU cycles;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't worry about performance - preoptimization is the root of all evil, and you might save a few nano seconds at best.

Use `for` loops when looping through a regular `0`, `1`, `2` array, and a `foreach` when using keys that aren't incrementing from 0.

Comment: Why should they use `for` on numerically indexed arrays?

Comment: @Jon I'm unaware if PHP saves all of its arrays the same ways (with incrementing keys / static keys etc.), but I can imagine that it's quicker to not have to look up the keys in the array before outputting it. A `foreach` would (essentially) *have* to look up the keys and *then* iterate through the array, whereas a for loop would just have to refer to the array length, but not have to look up the keys. I *might* be wrong about this, but would love some insight in case I am.

Comment: All arrays are saved in the same way: a combination of a hashtable (which offers fast lookups on arbitrary keys) and linked list (which offers ordering and deterministic iteration). `foreach` uses the linked list to iterate, so there is no lookup involved. Actually it's `for` that makes a lookup (because they are not "real" arrays, so on access the index is hashed and a lookup into the hashtable made).