# Better way to count and construct unique array in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code which takes rediculously long time to execute. Sometimes it even times out.

```
foreach ($totalownerships as $totalownership) {
    if (!in_array($totalownership['titleno'], $totaltitles)) {
        $result['totalowns'] += 1;
        $totaltitles[] = $totalownership['titleno'];
        $result['ownershipid'] = $result['ownershipid'] . " " .$totalownership['titleno'];
    }
}
```

The `$totalownerships` array size is `52225`. Is there a better way of writing this code so that it doesn'e take long time to execute ?

Comment: Probably be better to store it in a database and query that. Way faster and easier.

Comment: Make the `$totaltitles` into a hash rather than a dictionary. `in_array` is slow when compared to checking presence of a key in a hash.

Comment: Where does $totalownerships come from ? If it came from a database, maybe you should review your query to get only the rows you need so you won't need to filter it afterward.

Comment: @lracicot They are not duplicates and I cant eliminate them from the database side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be a lot faster, using PHP's speedy built-in array manipulation tools to eliminate array searches in a loop:

```
// Add all titles to $totaltitles, for added speed
foreach ($totalownerships as $totalownership) {
    $totaltitles[] = $totalownership['titleno'];
}

// For PHP 5.5+ you can use array_column() to get just the titleno field
//$totaltitles = array_column($totalownership, 'titleno');

// Use array_unique() to eliminate duplicate titles from $totaltitles
array_unique($totaltitles);

// Use count() to get a total count of $totaltitles
$result['totalowns'] = count($totaltitles);

// Use implode() for concatenation of title names
$result['ownershipid'] .= " " . implode(" ", $totaltitles);
```

For more PHP performance tips, check: [PHP Bench](http://www.phpbench.com)

Comment: PS - Edited the `for` loop back to a `foreach` - Although that doesn't seem to be your biggest performance hit, the foreach does seem to be the faster of them, per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php (note the benchmarks on answer 1)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using an `O(n)` in_array operation, I would use a `O(1)` keylook up:

```
$totaltitles = array();
foreach ($totalownerships as $totalownership) {
    if (!isset($totaltitles[$totalownership['titleno']])) {
        $totaltitles[$totalownership['titleno']] = $totalownership['titleno'];
        $result['ownershipid'] .= " " . $totalownership['titleno'];
    }
}
$result['totalowns'] = count($totaltitles);
```

Basically the idea is to just use your unique attribute as an array key so you can use a constant time lookup instead of a linear one.

---

If you wanted to take a (likely slower) prettier route, you could try:

```
$uniques = array_unqiue(array_map(function($own) { 
    return $own['titleno']; 
}, $totalownerships));
$result = array(
    'ownershipid' => implode(' ', $uniques), 
    'totalowns' => count($uniques)
);
```

(As Steven Moseley said, if you're using PHP 5.5, you can use array_column instead of that array_map call.)

Comment: +1 as it's always a good idea to try to reduce the complexity of operations.  In this case, unfortunately, it's still an `O(n)` operation, as `isset()` gets slower as `$totaltitles` gets bigger.  It's still going to be faster than the OP's code though.  Good creative thinking. :)

Comment: @StevenMoseley I didn't mean that overall it became O(1). There's an obvious &Omega;(n) on the overall operation since each element must be processed at least once. I just meant that the linear in_array operation can be replaced with a constant time hash table lookup. I guess I should have made it a bit clearer that the overall operation was going from quadratic to linear. :)

Comment: @StevenMoseley To be a bit clearer: isset() is constant time. `$totaltitles[$totalownership['titleno']]` is constant time. Therefore, `In this case, unfortunately, it's still an O(n) operation, as isset() gets slower as $totaltitles gets bigger` is wrong. It's still O(n) because an O(1) operation is performed n times. (Don't forget that the original was O(n^2) -- the change to isset from in_array knocked it down to O(n) by removing a O(n) operation)

Comment: Are you sure it's constant time?  It doesn't get any slower as the array grows?  Do you have a benchmark on that?

Comment: It definitely wouldn't be linear (implying a non associative container like a linked list or a linear search on a plain array). It would either be an ordered tree (likely a balanced one like a red black tree or an AVL tree) or a hash map (which is what I believe it is). https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5801811#file-constant_isset-php is a rather imperfect benchmark (non determinism in a benchmark makes me cry, but I was afraid of caching), but it's good enough to show that it's definitely constant time (which is strange since the manual implies a balanced tree).

Comment: @StevenMoseley I also checked with strings rather than integers thinking that maybe some arrays are hash tables and some are ordered trees, but no. Even with strings, it's still very obviously constant time.

Comment: @Corbin - Interesting stuff!  Thanks for taking the time to research this.  Good to know. :)