# How to change a foreach to a for loop?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I've read on a web page, explaining that in PHP it is must faster execution to do a for loop than a foreach. This is new to me, but I would like to test this for himself. How do I convert a foreach into a for loop in PHP? Using the one below as an example:

```
foreach ($station->ITEMS->ITEM as $trips=>$trip) {
    $ny_trips[$trips] = $trip;
}
```

I've seen for loops in PHP, but not using 'as' in them. So I'm not sure how the above would look in PHP as a for loop. Would it also require doing a count() of $station->ITEMS->ITEM? Thanks!

Comment: Is `$trips` a sequenced number?

Comment: Also the speed difference shouldn't be noticeable. [Clicky](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php)

Comment: @DaveChen $trips is the key in a $key=>$value.

Comment: I'd like to test this in my application and see what the actual timing difference is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuimg the keys on the array are a perfect numerical sequence starting at 0 then this is what you are looking for.

```
for($x = 0, $nItems = count($station->ITEMS->ITEM); $x<$nItems; $x++) {
    $ny_trips[$x] = $station->ITEMS->ITEM[$x];
}
```

If the keys are non-numeric then or not in perfect order then you need to do something like this.

```
$keys = array_keys($station->ITEMS->ITEM);
for($x = 0, $nItems =  count($station->ITEMS->ITEM);$x < $nItems; $x++) {
    $ny_trips[$keys[$x]] = $station->ITEMS->ITEM[$keys[$x]];
}
```

Comment: +1, doesn't need to start at zero, but it does need to be sequential.

Comment: @DaveChen Just said that because I initialized at $x to 0

Comment: I mean like with `reset` and `key`.

Comment: Thanks! I also decided to try this with $cnt = count($station->ITEMS->ITEM); before the loop. I figure no sense in calculating this value each time.

Comment: @edward Updated with an optimized and cached count call

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0;$i < count($station->ITEMS->ITEM);$i++){
   $ny_trips[$i] = $station->ITEMS->ITEM[$i];
}
```