# How to use a for loop on a collection pulled from Magento

Tags: php, magento

im trying to use a for loop on products i pulled from Magento.
And it crashes when i want to use the index on a product in the loop.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

$collectionLength = count($collection);
for($j = 0; $j < $collectionLength; $j++)
{
     $productFromStore = $collection[$j];//it crashes on this line of code
     $sku = $productFromStore->getSku();
}
```

but when i use a foreach loop i can reach all the products.

```
foreach($collection as $product)
{
     // this code works fine
     $sku = $product->getSku(); 
}
```

Can someone explain what is going wrong and why?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your getSku function and tell us what is the error you got ?

Comment: Well the getSku() is not the problem, it crashes when i wanna pull out the product with the index. $productFromStore = $collection[$j];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collection classes in Magento's ORM ultimately subclass [`Varien_Data_Collection`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php#L34) which implements `IteratorAggregate`; this is why you are able to work with the collection object in an array-like fashion (i.e. `foreach`), but not have it work for the `for` loop. For one thing, dThere is no direct key-based access to the elements inside the object (`_items` array members) - unfortunate, given that the key for the `_items` array is based on the row ID.

Bottom line: working with collection items in a `for` loop is not very easy, not when compared to the ease of working with collection items via `IteratorAggregate` and all of its related goodies.

Here's an example of both. If you have an overarching need to work with the collection's items directly then you can use `$collection->getItems()`, but again realize that the `_items` array keys may not be sequential as they are based on the data. Also, note that you need to add the `name` attribute value to collections stored using Magento's EAV pattern:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

include('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');

//for loop - not as much fun
for ($j=0;$j<count($collection);$j++) {  //count() triggers $collection->load()
    $items = $collection->getItems();
    $item = current($items);
    echo sprintf(
        "%d:\t%s\t%s\n",
        $k,
        $item->getSku(),
        $item->getName()
    );
    next($items); //advance pointer
}

//foreach - a bit better
foreach ($collection as $k => $product) {
    echo sprintf(
        "%d:\t%s\t%s\n",
        $k,
        $product->getSku(),
        $product->getName()
    );
}
```

And just in case you are wondering: [Performance of FOR vs FOREACH in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php)

Comment: Sure you don't want `$num = count( $collection );` and `$items = $collection->getItems();` before the `for` loop?

Comment: Also `$k` is not defined in `for` loop so it will always print `0`

Comment: For sure, ignore the `for`, not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, You trying to iterate collection object as array
Here is Error :

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type
>   Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection as array

, second for loop isn't the best way to iterate collections better is foreach loop becacuse for loop need to count of array emelents foreach dont need it.
Third, the best way is to use magento resource iterator.

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')
        ->walk(
           $query->getSelect(), 
           array(array($this,'callbackFunction')));
```

here is an example:

```
public function someGetCollectionMethod()
{
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')
              ->walk(
                   $products->getSelect(), 
                   array(array($this, 'productsCallback')));
}

public function productsCallback($args)
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $prod = $product->load($args['row']['entity_id']);
    Zend_Debug::dump($prod->getSku());
}
```

Happy coding,
Adam

Comment: Could you write some comments what you changed and what made his code go wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in magento, but perhaps it's because the collection has different keys other than just numbers? Try printing out the collection with [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to see what keys does the object have.

If you need iterations with numbers, you can always do something like that:

```
$i=0;
foreach($collection as $product)
{
     $sku = $product->getSku(); 
     $i++;
}
```

EDIT: Anyway, it seems collections aren't regular arrays, so you cannot use them the way you tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);
```

This type of array cannot be accessed by indexes you have to use,

```
$array["foo"];
```

If the keys are unpredictable you have to use

`foreach

Answer (score 0):

### That's because you are sending an empty value to the getSku function.

```
<?php
$collection=array("book1"=>"bat","book2"=>"cat");
$collectionLength = count($collection);
for($j = 0; $j < $collectionLength; $j++)
{
    $productFromStore = $collection[$j];
    echo $productFromStore; //prints nothing !
}

foreach($collection as $var)
{
    echo $var; //prints batcat
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In magento collection return in form of object. use below code fetch SKU and NAME. Or use `print_r($collection->getData())` to get data in array Key=>value format.

```
foreach($collection as $productCollection){
$sku = $productCollection->getSku();
$name = $productCollection->getName();
```

}