# Compare large sets of data in php

Tags: php

I have two arrays, `$posters (945 records)` and `$stats_results(6000 records)`. I am comparing both of these array with each other to find the records from `$posters` array in to `$stats_results` array. Everything works fine but it takes 90 or more seconds. How can I make this proccess faster. Here is what I have done.

```
 for ($j=0; $j < count($posters); $j++)//945 records
    { 
     for ($i=0; $i < count($stats_results) ; $i++)//6000 records
     {
        if($stats_results[$i]['path'] == '/'.$posters[$j]['path'])
        {
         if(date('Ymd',strtotime($stats_results[$i]['start_date']))>=date('Ymd',strtotime($posters[$j]['start_date'])) && date('Ymd',strtotime($stats_results[$i]['start_date']))<=date('Ymd',strtotime($posters[$j]['end_date']) ))
         {
             $stats[]=array(
               //I am storing filtered value in the array 
             );
         }
     }
  }
```

As I said everything works fine. No mameory issues. Is there any better way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Improved code based on suggestions. It works fine:

```
$posters_stats=array();
foreach ($posters as $key => $value)
{
  $path = '/'.$value['Identifier'];
  $posters_stats[$path]=array(
    'sdate'=>date('Ymd',strtotime($value['Presentation_Date'])),
    'enddate'=>date('Ymd',strtotime($value['Expiry_Date']))
  );
}
foreach ($stats as $key => $stats_result)
{
  if(isset($posters_stats[$stats_result["path"]]))
  {
    if(strtotime($stats_result["date"])>=strtotime($posters_stats[$stats_result["path"]]['sdate']))
     {
       echo "<pre>";
       print_r($stats_result);
     }
   }else{
       echo "<pre>";
       print_r($stats_result);
   }
}
```

Thank you all for the contribution :)

Comment: Take your calls to `count()` outside of your `for` statement. You have 6495 calls to it and you only need 2.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code review request. This is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Compare these records at `MySQL` level if they come from a database or reconsider your DB design for storing them. Nevertheless, doing about 5 million comparisons in PHP is not sane.

Comment: Look into using a `foreach()` construct instead of `for()`

Comment: Also, the syntax highlighter in your question clearly shows that you have some syntax errors

Comment: have you looked at a binary search method.

Comment: Thanks RobertPitt. I have implemented my code as user3351733 has suggested and it works great. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can transform your $posters array in the following form:

$posters[$path] = array("start_date"=>"...","end_date"=>"..");

then you can use

```
foreach ($stats_results as $key => $stats_result)
{
      if(array_key_exist($stats_result["path"] ,$posters))
      ...
}
```

faster will be

```
foreach ($stats_results as $key => $stats_result)
{
      if(isset($posters[$stats_result["path"]]))
      ...
}
```

So you have only 945 rounds instead of 945*6000.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I will implement this and see what different it makes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, just small question. How can I retrieve the $path from $posters array which is not exists in $stats_results array? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($posters as &$poster) {

    $stats[] = array_filter($stats_results, function($item) use ($poster) {

        return 
            ($item['path'] == '/' . $poster['path'] &&
            $item['start_date'] >= $poster['start_date'] &&
            $item['start_date'] <= $poster['end_date'];

    });

}
```

Use `array_filter` with a lambda function. I'm not sure this is what you want, but this snippet will add to $stats whatever $stats_results that fit the conditions.

This might be a little bit faster (I'm not sure why you're converting timestamps to date to make a comparison), this avoids counting the number of elements each time, avoids incrementing unnecessary variables ($j and $i). Doesn't avoid the crazy nested loops, but is more readable.

Comment: foreach is slower than a for cicle, better to use it

Comment: No, it's not. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php].

Comment: Thanks you all for suggestions. I will take all suggestions have been made and organise my code. Much appreciated.