# Populating table in writehtmlcell with foreach loop?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm trying to populate a table with the function writehtmlcell using a foreach loop.
I'm getting errors like null or something and invalid arguments supplied for foreach. Any idea?

The code is shown below.

```
$get_output = array(one, two, three, four, five);
$ctrword = 0;
$html .="<table>";
foreach ($get_output as $key) {
    $ctrword++;
    if(($ctrword % 5) == 0)
    {
       html .= "<tr>";

    }
    if(($ctrword%5)==1)
    {
       $html .= "<td>".$key."</td>";  

    }
    if(($ctrword%5)==5) 
    {
       $html .= "</tr>";

    }

 }          

$html .= "</table>";
pdf->WriteHtmlCell(0,0,'','',$html,1);
```

Comment: opps sorry w8.. let me update it.

Comment: i have used counter $ctrword++ so how come it will not be executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a)

```
html .= "<tr>";  // missing $html
```

b) if one,two... are not constant ,use below code

```
 $get_output = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five');
```

Comment: Like for a and b. But dislike for c. He is using $key to populate td. Moreover you can't say normal for loop is efficient than foreach. In the above case, it is calling the count function each and every time.

For more info on the same. Please refer the given SO link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php

Comment: Hi, it's weird I'm getting this error _Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null_ I already var_dump the variable it has values but this error prompt. hmm.. any idea for this?

Comment: in the above code we have not used array_push(), must me from other place

Comment: yes I know, I did not used array_push either. that's why it is weird to have that error. I also tested the loop you provided but same thing happened. I already check if the var has values, using var_dump, the values are there but seems there are problem.