# Large HTML tables and PHP loops

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays - let's say one contains 200 values, and the other one - 30. I need to make a HTML table with 200 rows for each array one value and 30 columns for each row from array two. 
The code:

```
<table>
    <?php foreach ($arrayOne as $arrayOneKey => $arrayOneValue) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $arrayOneValue; ?></td>
        <?php foreach ($arrayTwo as $arrayTwoKey => $arrayTwoValue) { ?>
            <td><?php echo $arrayTwoValue; ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
     </tr>
     <?php } ?>
 </table>
```

The problem with this is that the loops takes a lot of time, adding about 200 - 300 ms to page load speed. Also if many users are loading this simultaneously, it affects the server CPU by increasing the usage.

Is there any way to speed this up or make the table in a different way?

Thanks

Comment: _“The problem with this is that the loops takes a lot of time”_ – no, they most likely don’t, 6,000 loop iterations isn’t that much; more likely it is sending the generated output to the browser, and most of all the time it takes the browser to render it. Especially rendering large tables is something that does not perform very well, since the browser must calculate the dimensions of each single table cell content so that it knows how to lay out the whole table. You could possibly speed this up, if you can set widths for the table cells beforehand and specify `table-layout:fixed`for the table.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems and improved the situation by using [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net) and providing the data in JSON-Format in the script. Using [Pagination](http://datatables.net/development/pagination) we only looked at parts of the table, rendered on demand, and that speeded things up quite a bit. Not sure if it is applicable in your case though (if you insist on showing all data at a time, it probably won't help much).

Also, use Firefox or Chrome-Tools to evaluate where the time is spend:

- generation of HTML by your PHP-code
- transferring large volume of data to the client
- rendering on the client

and depending on the results you should get an idea in which area to optimize...

Comment: Also CBroe is right about fixed column widths, that also did a lot for me (and is doable with Datatables as well).

Answer (score 0):

do you try with implode your array ?

```
<table>
    <?php foreach ($arrayOne as $arrayOneValue) {
         echo "<tr><td>$arrayOneValue<td></td>".implode("</td><td>", $arrayTwo)."</td></tr>";
    ?>            
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited: Quick conclussion... fastest method is simple foreach.

I guess to be helpful trying to give you fresh alternative.  By default the foreach structure works copying instances for each iteration.  Try to pass by reference using ampersand. I ignore if it will be more optimized but let's try and post results.
Also let me give you a tip, use the alternative php tags for views and you will improve code readability.

Example:

```
<table>
    <?php foreach ($arrayOne as $arrayOneKey => &$arrayOneValue): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$arrayOneValue?></td>
        <?php foreach ($arrayTwo as &$arrayTwoKey => $arrayTwoValue): ?>
            <td><?=$arrayTwoValue?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
     </tr>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
 </table>
```

EDIT: Just found this explanation and benchmarking. Definetively passing by reference will be slower than simple foreach. Check this link:

[Performance of FOR vs FOREACH in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php)

EDIT2 : Not so simple. At the end of the day it seems to depend on context, data type and other factors. I have been playing with this script to benchmark differences between reference-passed foreach, normal foreach, for and while. Results gives best rates to normal foreach, so ... make your own conclussions.

```
<?php
$n = 1500000;

// Generating test array
$array = array();
$i = 0;
while($i < $n) {
  $array[] = $i++;
}

/**
 * Benchmark 
 */



// While
$time_start = microtime(true);
$i = 0;
$length = count($array);
while($i<$length) {
  $devnull = $array[$i++];
}
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time_while = $time_end-$time_start;
echo number_format($time_while, 3, '.', '')
  ." seconds - while()\n";


echo "<br>";


// Foreach
$time_start = microtime(true);
foreach($array as $a) {
  $devnull = $a;
}
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time_foreach = $time_end-$time_start;
echo number_format($time_foreach, 3, '.', '')
  ." seconds - foreach()\n";


echo "<br>";


// Foreach
$time_start = microtime(true);
foreach($array as &$a) {
  $devnull = $a;
}
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time_foreach = $time_end-$time_start;
echo number_format($time_foreach, 3, '.', '')
  ." seconds - ref-foreach()\n";



echo "<br>";


// For
$time_start = microtime(true);
$length = count($array);
for($i=0;$i<$length;++$i) {
  $devnull = $array[$i];
}
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time_for = $time_end-$time_start;
echo number_format($time_for, 3, '.', '')
  ." seconds - for()\n";

?>
```

Above scrpit is a self modified version of this one: http://juliusbeckmann.de/blog/php-foreach-vs-while-vs-for-the-loop-battle.html