# Most efficient way to loop though PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to iterate over an array and do something where the actual value of the array is not needed.  What is the most efficient way to do so?  If I do need to use the array element value, does the answer change?  I've given two possible solutions below.

```
<?php
$sql='INSERT INTO bla(x,y,z) ';
$myarray=array(4,3,6,9,6,3,6);

for ($i = 0; $i <= count($myarray); $i++) {
    //Do something where $myarray[$x] is not needed such as make a sting
    $sql.='(1,2,?),';
}

foreach($myarray as $arrayElement) {
    //Do something where $arrayElement is not needed such as make a sting
    $sql.='(1,2,?),';
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi,  Please comment why you feel this post should be closed.  Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performance of FOR vs FOREACH in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php)

Comment: Because it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Please stop micro-optimizing.

Comment: A quick search could have given you an answer, this questions has been asked many times.

Comment: If you are really interested in this, it seems like something you could benchmark yourself. Use `microtime` to time the loops with large sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, `for` is slightly faster than `foreach`, thus making it more efficient. Of course, the difference is so small that I doubt anyone can notice it in most occasions.

But `foreach` seems to be a more elegant way, and also in case of associative array it is your only choice.

Comment: It depends on the amount of items in the array actually.

Comment: How would you use `for` for an associative array?

Comment: @jeroen, the OP doesn't need the value, so in this case it would be fine to use a `for` loop, but I think you're right that ussually a `for` loop is useless for an associative array.

Comment: @mariobgr It most definitely does not.

Comment: ok, I gave it a try. you win :)

Comment: "How would you use `for` for an associative array?" Like so `for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){echo current($a);next($a);}`. Kind of useless but functional nevertheless

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to use the value, then `for` is a bit faster.
If you need to alter the values of the array then the `foreach` loop with `reference` is the fastest.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3433065/2078780