# Simple array foreach

Tags: php

I'm sure this is very simple ... But I can't seem to figure it out. I need to send an email to each of the email addresses mentioning the points. But both emails have 36 points.

```
$emails = $userTools->weeklyMail();
```

print_r:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => email1@gmail.com
            [1] => 
            [2] => 36
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => email2@gmail.com
            [1] => 
            [2] => 25
        )

)
```

Loop:

```
foreach($emails as $email)
{
        $email = $email[0];
        $subject = "You have ".$email[2]." points!!! !!!";
        // The message
        $message = "Hello\r\nYou have ".$email[2]." points .";
        $helperClass->sendEmail($email, $subject, $message);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you overwrite the reference variable `$email` which means `$email[2]` is undefined.

Change to:

```
foreach($emails as $email)
{
        // $email = $email[0]; You can't use $email[2] if $email is overwritten
        $subject = "You have ".$email[2]." points!!! !!!";
        // The message
        $message = "Hello\r\nYou have ".$email[2]." points .";
        $helperClass->sendEmail($email[0], $subject, $message);
}
```

Comment: I personally went with the for loop right after posting the question and it worked, but your problem solves the problem as posted in the question. Just to know ... which is faster? Foreach of For? Thank you!

Comment: @ciprian, As far as preformance, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php, however, there is no doubt that the `foreach` is safer. For example, what happens when you delete an element of the array so that an index is missing?  It'll break your code in a for loop. With foreach, it's not a problem.

Comment: Yeah ... that's true. I just added the id to the `$emails` query and had to change the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the line

```
$email = $email[0];
```

Then change the last line :

```
$helperClass->sendEmail($email[0], $subject, $message);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $count_emails=count($emails);
 for($i=0;$i<$count_emails;$i++)
 {
    $email_addr = $email[$i][0];
    $subject = "You have ".$email[$i][2]." points!!! !!!";
    // The message
    $message = "Hello\r\nYou have ".$email[2]." points .";
    $helperClass->sendEmail($email_addr, $subject, $message);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

so after $email = $email[0]; you reassign foreach variable $email. and in variable $email we have ONLY email address.  in other code where you use $email[2], PHP return 3rd symbol of string with mail.

try this code

```
foreach($emails as $email)
{
        $email_address = $email[0];
        $points = $email[2];

        $subject = "You have ".$points." points!!! !!!";
        // The message
        $message = "Hello\r\nYou have ".$points." points .";
        $helperClass->sendEmail($email_address, $subject, $message);
}
```