# how to populate data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, export, phpword

usually when i run this query it would always fetch all of the data in the table. but now its just taking a row of the data in the table.
Im trying to export the data to Microsoft Wor by using phpword.

how to solve this?

```
$order_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id), BuyerName,BuyerEmail,BuyerAddress,TransactionID,ItemAmount,DateTime FROM `order`") 
or die(mysql_error());
$x= 0;
$y= 0;
// Add table
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($order_query))
    {

$x++;
$y++;

// Add table style      
$PHPWord->addTableStyle('myOwnTableStyle."$x".', $styleTable, $styleFirstRow);
$PHPWord->addTableStyle('myOwnTableStyle."$y".', $styleTable, $styleFirstRow);

//create table
$table1 = $section->addTable('myOwnTableStyle."$x".');

// Add row
$table1->addRow(900);  

    $f1 = $row['BuyerName'];
    $f2 = $row['BuyerEmail'];
    $f3 = $row['BuyerAddress'];
    $f4 = $row['TransactionID'];
    $f5 = $row['ItemAmount'];
    $f6 = $row['DateTime'];

// Add cells
$table1->addCell(2000, $styleCell)->addText('Nama', $fontStyle);
$table1->addCell(2000, $styleCell)->addText('Email', $fontStyle);
$table1->addCell(2000, $styleCell)->addText('Alamat', $fontStyle);
$table1->addCell(2000, $styleCell)->addText('ID Transaksi', $fontStyle);
$table1->addCell(2000, $styleCell)->addText('Jumlah', $fontStyle);
$table1->addCell(2000, $styleCell)->addText('Tarikh', $fontStyle);


// Add more rows / cells

    $table1->addRow();
    $table1->addCell(2000)->addText("$f1");
    $table1->addCell(2000)->addText("$f2");
    $table1->addCell(2000)->addText("$f3");
    $table1->addCell(2000)->addText("$f4");
    $table1->addCell(2000)->addText("$f5");
    $table1->addCell(2000)->addText("$f6");



$table = $section->addTable('myOwnTableStyle."$y".');


$table->addRow(900);

$table->addCell(2000, $styleCell)->addText('Nama Barang', $fontStyle);
$table->addCell(2000, $styleCell)->addText('Kod Barang', $fontStyle);
$table->addCell(2000, $styleCell)->addText('Kuantiti Barang', $fontStyle);

//2nd query for details
$detail_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orderlist WHERE TransactionID  = '$f4'");
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($detail_query))

    {   

    $fd1 = $rows['ItemName'];
    $fd2 = $rows['ItemNumber'];
    $fd3 = $rows['ItemQTY'];

    $table->addRow();
    $table->addCell(2000)->addText("$fd1");
    $table->addCell(2000)->addText("$fd2");
    $table->addCell(2000)->addText("$fd3");



    }
    unset($table);
    unset($table1);

    }
```

Comment: You're creating a new table for each row. Create the table outside the loop.

Comment: thats what i really want to do so dont mind that.

Comment: Then each table in Word will be just one row from the database table.

Comment: like i say, i wanted to do that. but i only got 1 table. actually the code is a lot more than that. i got other sub table for that that shows order details. so for each row of both the table in my database is going to be input in different row in table on words. but the problems is. it didnt really goes the way i want as it is only show 1 row of data from each of the table.

Comment: Plus, `X++;` that `X` is treated as a [**constant**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php). It's in uppercase on top of that.

Comment: ops my bad on copy paste. im using `$x++;`

Comment: question is too, where is `$x` initially assigned? and are you checking for errors? and using `mysql_` to connect with, right? and not `mysqli_` or PDO.

Comment: i know about the problem with mysql_ and how there's rumors that been going on about it. this is just for my final year project and not an actual site . `$x` is asign before the loop. i cant show my whole code because it says too much code and not enough explanation.

Comment: You added the query for everything but `$order_query`. Make sure that query isn't failing you, or that you didn't set it wrong. and I doubt you want to use a `while` but a `foreach`. Your `$x` probably isn't incrementing properly because of it. Example `for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {...}` but that's a `for` loop. See this answer on those loops http://stackoverflow.com/a/3430538/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just unset `$table` variable before ending the loop

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($order_query))
{
    $x++;
    $table = $section->addTable('myOwnTableStyle'.$x);

    ....

    unset($table);
}
```

Comment: Assuming the `X` [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) has already been assigned.

Comment: Yes, as he said in comments that **actually the code is a lot more than that** so I'm assuming that.

Comment: You're welcome. Now let's see what the OP has to say ;-) *fingers crossed*

Comment: so if i set it like `$x++;` will x be change or still in constant state?

Comment: value of `$x` will increase by 1 in every loop. But it's better to assign `$x` before starting `while` loop. like `$x = 0;`

Comment: already did assign it before the loop. but still doesnt work. it just export data from the 1st row of each table

Comment: @Chayan I have a feeling their loop method may be failing them with the `while`, rather than a `for` or a `foreach`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- can u show the change source code using `foreach` in answer panel? already try change it and i get an error. i dont really know the right syntax to use `foreach`

Comment: @MohdFadli I left you a link example under your question. I really have to go to sleep here. See if Chayan can help out further, my mind has gone to mush. I hope this gets resolved, *cheers*

Comment: i do know how to implement `foreach` to use `explode` but never did use `foreach` to get the data.

Comment: @MohdFadli change `'myOwnTableStyle."$x".'` to as I stated in my answer. And so on..

Comment: @MohdFadli Problem is in your first query. You are using `COUNT` and it's a group function. If you do not use `GROUP BY` it will return only 1 row. you can check your query in your `phpmyadmin` directly.

Comment: @Chayan how to check my query using `phpmyadmin`?

Comment: [Running SQL queries on a database with phpMyAdmin](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYSrVjSi7IU)

Comment: Glad to see a green tick to the answer. I had a feeling it was their initial query. Had it been initially shown, would have expedited the process.