# how to open docx file using source code when using php[phpword]

Tags: php, phpword

is there a source code to open a file using php? the type of file is `.docx`

```html
  
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('AdvancedTable.docx');
```

Comment: Apparently and according to the docs on http://phpword.codeplex.com/ the library is only for creating not reading/parsing documents.

Comment: then there's no alternative code to open external file?

Comment: Ar you using this library? https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_11_ReadWord2007.php

Comment: this is my source code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556757/how-to-populate-data-in-mysql/32556957?noredirect=1#comment52970640_32556957

Comment: interesting, but  exactly which _library_ do you use?

Comment: http://phpword.codeplex.com/

Comment: Then the answer is still: no. But the phpword project at github seems to have reader implementations.

Comment: even just open it using microsoft word? not to import or anything. just to open the file. is it really not possible?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the last comment. What do you mean?

Comment: a simple command to execute the file to open. not possible?

Comment: like after `phpword` succes in creating `AdvancedTable.docx`, i want the file to be open in microsoft word.

Comment: If it's a windows machine `shell_exec('start c:\\temp\\moo.docx');` would open the document `c:\temp\\moo.docx` in the default-application for `.docx`. But this would happen on the machine where php runs (the server, if you have a client-server setup) under the user credentials of the php process (which by the common/default httpd win32-install would be localsystem without an associated desktop).

Comment: im going to try that method tomorrow, not at my desk right now.

Comment: VolkerK put at answer works great ;-) im using this `shell_exec('start C:/xampp/htdocs/Payang/PHPWord/Examples/AdvancedTable.docx');`

Comment: actually a simple `shell_exec('start AdvancedTable.docx');` works great.