# How can I loop through multidimensional array without using foreach

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Looping through a multidimensional array requires `foreach` loop in PHP usually so I was wondering can it be done using the

```
for(int $i=0;i<3;$i++)
```

format.

example of multidimensional array:

```
$array = array (array(3,4,5,7), array('r', 'g', 'q','c'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use a [for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) or a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

For example:

```
$array = array (array(3,4,5,7), array('r', 'g', 'q','c'));
for($x=0; $x < 2; $x++) {
    for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) {
        echo $array[$x][$i];
    }
}
```

Foreach example:

```
$array = array (array(3,4,5,7), array('r', 'g', 'q','c'));
foreach($array as $parent) {
    foreach($parent as $values) {
        echo $values;
    }
}
```

Output:

> 3457rgqc

Comment: if you didn't know the length of the arrays, instead of $i<4 what could you use instead. $x<count($array)-1 perhaps?

Comment: You could put in `count($array[$x])`. This is not the best for performance though. Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php

Answer (score 3):

```
$array = [ [3, 4, 5, 7], ['r', 'g', 'q', 'c'] ];

array_walk_recursive(
    $array,
    function(&$value, &$key) {
        echo "$key => $value\n";
    }
);
```