# Compare array items against other items in array one time

Tags: php

I have a PHP array that has from 2-5 items in it.

```
$z=["itema", "itemb", "itemc", "itemd","iteme"];
```

I need to have a way to go through the array and match each item against each other one time. So the output would look like

```
itema vs itemb
itema vs itemc
itema vs itemd
itema vs iteme

itemb vs itemc
itemb vs itemd
itemb vs iteme

itemc vs itemd...ect
```

I can not seem to get the loop to hit every item. I think it has to be a loop in a loop since my just one loop doesn't work.

And it has to go to each only once. I am so lost on how to get this to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the code that you have so far - it will help users to pinpoint possible problems with your solution. Also describe how exactly the code fails to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use two for loops

```
$count = count($z);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count - 1; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
        // compare $z[$i] with $z[$j]...
    }
}
```

The other loop goes from 0 to n - 2 and the inner loop takes the value from the outer value as initial and goes to the end.

---

If you also need to handle associative arrays, like one commenter mentioned, you could use `array_values` (and `array_keys`) to handle this case.

```
$values = array_values($z);
$keys = array_keys($z); // optional - only used, if you need the keys..
$count = count($values);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count - 1; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
        // compare $values[$i] with $values[$j]...
        // or $keys[$i] with $keys[$j];
    }
}
```

> Note: A `foreach` loop won't work in either case, because you can't
>   told the inner loop to skip all values, already seen in the outher
>   loop. And teaching the `foreach` loop this behavior would result in a
>   `foreach`, that effectly *looks like* a simple `for` loop and *is slower*.
>   There's simply no benefit in using a `foreach`.

Comment: Thats it ! than you very much. I figured I needed an inner loop but I could not get it right.

Comment: @Philipp congrats on 10k

Comment: I down voted it because this approach doesn't work with string key array's. It's better to use `foreach` instead of `for`, please see this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741890/compare-array-items-against-other-items-in-array-one-time/33742003#33742003

Comment: @Julian - 1. assoc arrays wasn't the authors problem. 2. The "better" approach is not what the author wants, as this compares `[1,2]` and also `[2,1]`. If you can't use numeric indices, you could first apply `array_values` to `$z` and if you also need the key, there is more to done. But just using a `foreach` doesn't work!

Comment: @Philipp You are right about `array_values()` but it's wrong to say that a `foreach` won't work. Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741890/compare-array-items-against-other-items-in-array-one-time/51499288#answer-51499288

Comment: @Julian and that is still a bad solution, because it needs double loop iterations and a unnecessary if condition. And if you read my updated answer carefully (especially the note on bottom), you would see, that I didn't wrote, it's impossible, but ugly. But feel free to give me any reason, why a foreach is cleaner or better

Comment: @Philipp You are calling `count()` in both for loops. This means that `count()` will be called every iteration. It feels like counting all the legs of the sheep and diving by 4 to get the number of sheeps. The `foreach` idiom doesn't suffer this weirdness. Therefore it's better. Note that I'm not trying to troll. It's just my opinion.

Comment: @Julian You could move the count outside the loop, but even if you don't do this, the foreach approach is two times slower! (`3.89s` vs `6.92s`) If you don't believe me, simply execute your code and my code. On top of that - if you move the `count` outside, the foreach approach is 4!! time slower (`1.81s` vs `7.39s`). Tested with `$z = range(0,20000);`

Comment: @Philipp I did a little benchmarking. You are right, the `for` loop is quicker if you would count before the `for`. But please have a loot at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php#answer-3430538

Comment: You didn't get my point - the foreach loop has to look at each of the `n*n` elements, altought only `n*(n-1)/2` elements are really important. And exactly that is what the for loop does.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but something like:

```
foreach($z as $item){
  foreach($z as $item2){
    if($item!=$item2){
      echo $item . ' vs ' . $item2;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$z=["itema", "itemb", "itemc", "itemd","iteme"];

$sizeZ=count($z);
for ($i = 0; $i < $sizeZ-1; $i++) 
{
    for ($j = $i+1; $j < $sizeZ; $j++) 
    {
        echo $z[$i]." vs ".$z[$j]."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

**Output :**

```
itema vs itemb
itema vs itemc
itema vs itemd
itema vs iteme
itemb vs itemc
itemb vs itemd
itemb vs iteme
itemc vs itemd
itemc vs iteme
itemd vs iteme
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's better to use a `foreach()` then a `for()`.

The approach with the `foreach()` looks cleaner to me. The approach with the `for()` is not wrong, but it's strange.

See the example with a `foreach`:

```
$z = array('xxApple' => "itema", 'B' => "itemb", 'C' => "itemc", 'D' => "itemd", 'AAAA' => "iteme");
//$z = array("itema", "itemb", "itemc", "itemd", "iteme"); // works also with this array

$x = array_values($z);
$y = array_keys($z); // Optional
foreach($x as $key1 => $item){
  foreach($x as $key2 => $item2){

    if($key2 <= $key1){
        continue;
    }

    if($item == $item2){
        continue;
    }

    echo $item . ' vs ' . $item2 . '<br>';
    // echo $y[$key1] . ' vs ' . $y[$key2] . '<br>'; // Optional
  }
}


//OUTPUT
itema vs itemb
itema vs itemc
itema vs itemd
itema vs iteme
itemb vs itemc
itemb vs itemd
itemb vs iteme
itemc vs itemd
itemc vs iteme
itemd vs iteme
```

---

Here are the benchmark results:

**Benchmark #1**

```
$z = range(0,20000);

$start = time();
$values = array_values($z);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($values) - 1; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($values); $j++) {
    }
}
$end = time();                  
$elapsedTimeA = $end - $start;

// Case A, elapsed time in seconds: 275
echo 'Case A, elapsed time in seconds: ' . $elapsedTimeA; 


$start = time();
$x = array_values($z);
foreach($x as $key1 => $item){
  foreach($x as $key2 => $item2){

    if($key2 <= $key1){
        continue;
    }

    if($item == $item2){
        continue;
    }
  }
}
$end = time();                   
$elapsedTimeB = $end - $start;

// Case B, elapsed time in seconds: 103
echo 'Case B, elapsed time in seconds: ' . $elapsedTimeB;
```

**Benchmark #2**

```
$z = range(0,20000);

$start = time();
$values = array_values($z);
$count = count($values);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count - 1; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
    }
}

$end = time();                  
$elapsedTimeA = $end - $start;

// Case A, elapsed time in seconds: 17
echo 'Case A, elapsed time in seconds: ' . $elapsedTimeA;


$start = time();
$x = array_values($z);
foreach($x as $key1 => $item){
  foreach($x as $key2 => $item2){

    if($key2 <= $key1){
        continue;
    }

    if($item == $item2){
        continue;
    }
  }
}
$end = time();                   
$elapsedTimeB = $end - $start;

// Case B, elapsed time in seconds: 103
echo 'Case B, elapsed time in seconds: ' . $elapsedTimeB;
```

Comment: Why the big difference in case A? Also, what hardware is the benchmark running on?