# for vs foreach in php (situational use)

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

The questions that I saw asked on this topic mainly revolved around performance/speed comparisons. I'm very familiar with JavaScript `for` loops and how to approach them when using arrays, for example (and I know this topic isn't about JavaScript, but just writing this to show my understanding of loops/arrays up to now):

```
var arr = [1,3,5];
for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

PHP is telling me that for arrays, I should navigate them using `foreach` loops. But both of the below loop styles below produce the same result.

```
<?php
    $arr = array(1,3,5);

    foreach($arr as $numbers) {
        echo "Number is: {$numbers}<br>";
    }

    for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {
        echo "Number is: " . $arr[$i] . "<br>";
    }
?>
```

I understand that the summary of a standard response is "Well there's more to it than that." Can someone quickly explain the overall benefit to using `foreach` for arrays over `for` and if it is has other applications outside of arrays?

Comment: arrays in php are actually hashmaps, so indexes can be out of order

Comment: What if your array indexes don't start at 0.  What if you have an associative array? `$arr = array(1=>1,3=>3,5=>5);` or `$arr = array('a'=>1,'b'=>3,'c'=>5);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php

Comment: Don't you think its also easier for the developer to write a foreach-loop instead of a for-loop?

Comment: If you do something like: `$arr = [ 1,2,3,4,5]` and then `unset($arr[2])` you'll see why it's best to avoid for loops in PHP.

Comment: @LPK There are many instances where I know there was syntax created in code to make certain tasks easier. There isn't THAT much more typing in the `for` than the `foreach`. Why wouldn't that have been made for JavaScript as well then? That last question isn't one that needs an answer, just a thought about why is it in PHP but not Javascript.

Comment: @AbraCadaver That's a good point. My chapters just went into associative arrays but haven't gone into the use of them with loops just yet.

Comment: @Lashane ooh also a good way for me to think about Arrays in PHP as opposed to JS.

Comment: "Why wouldn't that have been made for JavaScript as well then?" - What do you mean with "that"?

Comment: @LPK I was getting at there is no `foreach` in JavaScript that I'm aware of. But searching now gave me this. But PHP shows me foreach when introducing loops whereas I've never seen this JavaScript method before (I'm young with JS, but still this wasn't shown to me in any JavaScript tutorials) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
$arrayItems = (count($array) - 1);
for ($i = 0, $i <= $arrayItems; $i++) {
    echo $array[$i];
}
```

If the array keys are associative using a string or some sort of "id" for keys (this is typical when iterating arrays of DB results), then that code doesn't work. Using foreach will cover the use cases.

If memory serves, foreach might be a fractional bit faster, under the hood, as well.

Comment: One minor adjustment - if you assign `count($array)` to a variable before initialising the loop PHP doesn't have to count the loop each iteration. A minor performance saving, but noticeable. If you're doing anything that requires a count (using an `$i` variable for instance) then using a `for` loop is just as sensible as `foreach`.

Comment: True, even though it was pseudo code, I edited the answer, just in case.

Comment: why do you skip last element of array?

Comment: I updated the code example. I probably should have thought about the code example, but I sketched it out just to show something as a visual aid. I'll try to keep away from doing that in the future.

Comment: @Lashane - it's not skipping the last element. The key of the first element in the array is `0`, so the final element's key will be `count($array) -1`