# foreach execution time issue with cakephp 3

Tags: php, performance, time, foreach, cakephp-3.0

I have an issue with foreach statement, it's take 9secs to browse 2000 items. And I don't know why.

```
$query = $table->find('all');
foreach($query as $a)
  $numresult
```

Environment:Apache 2.0 Handler, PHP Version 5.6.22-0+deb8u1, cakephp 3.0
Many Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Use a profiler (like [**XDebug**](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler)) to figure where _exactly_ the time is spent, and come back with the results. For starters [**DebugKit**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/debug-kit.html) might help (check the Timers and SQL Log tabs), maybe the time is actually spent executing the query, who knows, queries are being lazy evaluated, in your case it will happen when the query objects iterator is being requested for `foreach`.