# React.js right way to iterate over object instead of Object.entries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I don't like using `Object.entries(object).map((key, i)` because I found out that this is an experimental technology of ECMAScript 7 and I feel that something may go wrong on production. Are there any native javascript alternative?

I have no problems with values of name, price, description because I know exactly where they should be rendered and I can access them with Populate.key, but for the characteristics, I need to literate over object and render both key and value.

I tried to use `Object.keys(priceChars).map(function(key, i)` but didn't understand how to separate key from value. Like, it was rendering "performance 500", but I need performance word to be in a icon class, and 500 is an actual value to be displayed.

My JSON structure

```
const Populate = {
  'name': "Product",
  'price': "1000",
  'description': "Product description",
  'characteristics': {
    'performance': '500',
    'pressure': '180',
    'engine': '4',
    'size': '860*730*1300',
    'weight': '420'
  }
}
```

And component

```
class PriceBlock extends Component {
  render() {
    const {priceName, priceDesc, priceVal, priceChars} = this.props;
    const characteristics = Object.entries(priceChars).map((key, i) => {
      return (
        <div className="price__icon-row" key={i}>
          <i className={'ico ico-' + key[0]}></i> <span>{key[1]}</span>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="col-5 price__block">
        <div className="price__name">{priceName}</div>
        <div className="price__description">{priceDesc}</div>
        <div className="price__icons">
          {characteristics}
        </div>
        <div className={ managePriceClass(priceVal) }>{priceVal}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Endless: This question has basically nothing to do with React.

Comment: If you're using a compiler like Babel, it shouldn't be a concern as long as your configuration is properly set.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

```
a = { 
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}

Object.keys(a).map(function(keyName, keyIndex) {
  // use keyName to get current key's name
  // and a[keyName] to get its value
})
```

A newer version, using destructuring and arrow functions. I'd use this one for new code:

```
a = { 
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}

Object.entries(a).map(([key, value]) => {
    // Pretty straightforward - use key for the key and value for the value.
    // Just to clarify: unlike object destructuring, the parameter names don't matter here.
})
```

Comment: is there also an elegant way to exclude `__typename`?

Comment: What's `__typename`?

Comment: how to pass the key reference 'this' into nested code?

Comment: @meadlai you need to convert the anonymous function as an arrow function. So, instead of `function(keyName, keyIndex) { ... }` you need to do `(keyName, keyIndex) => { ... }`

Comment: nadavvadan: "The __typename field is a so-called "meta field" (part of the GraphQL specification) which power its introspection (and similar functionality). It represents the name of the GraphQL object type being queried." (quote lifted from https://spectrum.chat/graphql/general/what-is-typename-in-apollo-link-state~b4851dc8-db06-4e12-a277-e030e907535f?m=MTUyNjA0OTU0NzAzNg== )

Comment: What if the data structure is deep? With object inside objects, How do we then access the deepest child?

Comment: @HarshPhoujdar sounds like a different question altogether. However, accessing a value inside an object always has the same syntax - either dot notation (`x.y`) or bracket notation (`x[“y”]`)

Comment: This example is really bare with no explanation.

Comment: @JGallardo - I find it simple and self-explanatory. Feel free to suggest an edit

Comment: How about performance? Is `Object.entries()` being triggered for each iteration?

Comment: @WoodrowShigeru why would that be the case? It’s only called once.

Comment: But a `map()` method is called on it. I'm not 100% sure how JavaScript chaining as seen here works in terms of order – so I'm asking. I'm referring to some behavior like this where it makes sense to cache the array: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3430538/2126442

Comment: @WoodrowShigeru think about it like that - Object.entries(x).map is the same as const a = Object.entries(x); a.map

Answer (score 14):

Complete function render in react

```
const renderbase = ({datalist}) => {
        if(datalist){
            return  Object.keys(datalist).map((item,index) => {
                return(
                  <option value={datalist[item].code} key={index}>
                      {datalist[item].symbol}
                  </option>
                )
            })
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this inside JSX braces instead of as a function?

Answer (score 5):

In a JSX function you can do this:

```
export default function ObjectList() {

  item = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  }

  return(
    {Object.entries(item).map(([key, value]) => (  
      <p>`Key: ${key}, Value: ${value}`</p>
    ))}
  )
}
```

Comment: Seems to be identical to the five year old answer above...

Comment: @MoritzRingler Someone asked if it was possible to do this in JSX braces and as a function, which none of the examples above did. It's very similar, but just different enough that some may prefer it over the other answers.