# React/Javascript - Function returns before finished executing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a function, which accepts an object and parses through to build a search query. The problem I am having is that this function returns before I have looped through the object:

```
export default function buildQuery(query) {

    let buildQuery = "?", pushAmpersand;
    Object.keys(query).map((v, i) => {
        i === 0 ? pushAmpersand = "" : pushAmpersand = "&";
        buildQuery += pushAmpersand + v + "=" + query[v];
    });

    console.log('Finished executing?');
    console.log(buildQuery);
    return buildQuery;
}
```

The return value is "?" - from having set the string at the start. Why is it not waiting until I have looped over the object?

I gather this is because it is an "asynchronous" function, so is this the place where I am supposed to introduce a promise, or a callback? It is my first time encountering a problem like this.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You're using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) incorrectly. It's not a replacement for a normal loop. `map` should return values into a new array. Try `forEach` instead.

Comment: Based off many other answers (e.g: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950546/react-js-right-way-to-iterate-over-object-instead-of-object-entries) this is a valid way to loop through an object in React to retrieve key value pairs. This has nothing to do with why my function is returning before it is finished.

Comment: And I'm telling you you're using map incorrectly. Look at that example in the link you provided. `map` is _returning_ a value to create a _new array_. Did you at least _try_ `forEach`?

Comment: @Andy it should still make buildQuery as `buildQuery += pushAmpersand + v + "=" + query[v]`  will execute inside the callback function everytime.

Comment: Well, if you're using `map` like that good luck in your code reviews.

Comment: @Notorious can you show what query you passed to the function

Comment: Ahh dammit, so sorry guys but thanks Djj your comment has had me realise what I am passing is an empty object. I am passing through an object I have just setState with, looks like state has not updated before I sent this.state.query as an argument to the function call. Also thanks for your comments Andy, I will look more into the differences between map and forEach as yes I am probably using the wrong one. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Rather then using a `map` you can use [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
export default function buildQuery(query) {    
    let buildQuery = "?";
    Object.keys(query).forEach((v, i) => {
        if( i !== 0 ) buildQuery += "&";
        buildQuery += (v + "=" + query[v]);
    });    
    console.log('Finished executing?');
    console.log(buildQuery);
    return buildQuery;
}
```