# Looping through simple object properties in react JSX

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to loop through a very simple object's properties in JSX. I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950546/react-js-right-way-to-iterate-over-object-instead-of-object-entries/40950656) other post and written my code the same way although I'm getting an error 'Can't find variable: a'. If I recall correctly, using a for in loop is not considered best practice with react.

Can someone offer some guidance as to where I'm going wrong?

I've made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vnw6jz) (click on subs and then view any sub), otherwise the code is below:

/components/sub.js:

```
import React from "react";

export default class SingleSub extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return (
        <div>
            {this.props.sub.entries(a).map(([key, value]) => {
                key, value
            })}
        </div>
      )
  }
}
```

/pages/sub.js - note line `<SingleSub sub={this.state.sub} />`

```
import React from 'react'
import SingleSub from '../components/sub.js'

export class SubPage extends React.Component {
    state = {
        loading: true,
        sub: null
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const url = 'https://em-app-basic.herokuapp.com/emails-api';
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({
            loading: false,
            sub: data.subs.find(sub => sub._id === this.props.match.params._id)
        })
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return <div>loading sub...</div>
        }
    
        if (!this.state.sub) {
            return <div>no sub to load.</div>
        }

        return (
            <div className="sub-details-individual">
                <h1 class="std-intro">Viewing a Single Subscriber</h1>
                <div className="sub-specs">
                    <div className="sub-specs-inner">
                        <SingleSub sub={this.state.sub} />
                        <div class="sub-spec">
                            <div className="sub-spec-detail">Name:</div>
                            <div className="sub-spec-value"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sub-spec">
                            <div className="sub-spec-detail">ID:</div>
                            <div className="sub-spec-value">{this.props.match.params._id}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

An example object:

[image]

Thanks for any help here.

UPDATE:

latest code that now outputs key and value but now html is output as string rather than real html:

```
import React from "react";

export default class SingleSub extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return (
        <div>
            {Object.entries(this.props.sub).map(([key, value]) => 
                `<div class="sub-spec">
                    <div class="sub-spec-detail">
                        ${key}
                    </div>
                    <div class="sub-spec-value">
                        ${value}
                    </div>
                </div> `
            )}
        </div>
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: What's `a` supposed to be? `entries` should be called via `Object.entries(someObject)` as per [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `sub.js`, try changing,

from,

```
{this.props.sub.entries(a).map(([key, value]) => {
   key, value
})}
```

to,

```
{Object.entries(this.props.sub).map(([key, value]) => {
   key, value
})}
```

Comment: better but not solved. I can now output the key and value, but the problem now is adding html is just rendered as text rather than html (using backticks) - question updated with the latest code

Comment: stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-irxst4?file=src%2Fcomponents%2Fsub.js - click on subs then view any sub