# PHP function that builds array from page vars that match keys from array?

Tags: php, arrays, function

So pretend we have an array like this:

```
$out = array('SOME_DATE' => 'some_date', 'ERROR_THING' => 'error_thing');
```

This array goes into a legacy proprietary function that takes the values and creates PHP vars out of them like this:

```
$some_date = 'the SOME_DATE return value';
$error_thing = 'the ERROR_THING return value';
```

However, I want to just put that `$out` array into a function that parses its values and returns an associative array like this:

```
['some_date'] => 'the SOME_DATE return value'
['error_thing'] => 'the ERROR_THING return value'
```

I'm not finding a PHP function or combination of functions yet that does this, so right now I have to pass the `$out` array through a for loop each time to create a new array to pass to our debug function:

```
foreach($out as $key => $val) {
    $new_out[$val] = $$val;
}
```

I could make my own "top-level" function, which is unfortunately not guaranteed to work everywhere due to our clunky legacy code, so if there's some PHP function or combo of functions I can use, that's much more preferable.

Comment: Can you write your expected output? Or define your question in short, it is unclear to me what you want to do.

Comment: Let us know your expected output please.

Comment: OK I edited it with examples and expected output.

Comment: @DaveHeq, You want to pass each of your values in an array to a function and get a new array with the results in it without any loops. Do I get it right?

Comment: @SühaBoncukçu - Pretty much (though oversimplified); I need a array of the input keys and the values assigned to the generated PHP vars, without having to do more than run a function. My only option right now is a top-level function, which isn't guaranteed to exist in the file I need to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read your question as "I have an array where each element has a function name as the key, and a function parameter as the value. I need to return an array where each element has the original parameter as the key, and the function's return as the value." Hopefully that's correct.

Using [`array_walk`](https://www.php.net/array-walk), you can apply a function to each element of the array. The callback is passed both the key and the value, making it simple to run your defined function. In addition, I'm [`use`-ing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-3) the new array by reference so I can update it with each pass. I've replaced your functions with some built-in ones here for demo purposes:

```
<?php
$out = ["strtoupper"=>"some_date", "strrev"=>"error_thing"];
$new_out = [];
array_walk(
    $out,
    function ($v, $k) use (&$new_out) {
        $new_out[$v] = function_exists($k) ? $k($v): null;
    }
);
print_r($new_out);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [some_date] => SOME_DATE
    [error_thing] => gniht_rorre
)
```

Comment: This is probably the cleanest answer, but unfortunately gives me syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION on PHP 5.2 (which is what our legacy site is running on), so I'm thinking there isn't a better solution than creating a top-level function then just running it in the debug function call.

Comment: Oh yes, this assumes a modern version of PHP. Running software that's been EOL for 6 years is very very dangerous. Do whatever you can to get it upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

My initial response, as follows:

```
<?php
$out = array('SOME_DATE' => 'some_date', 'ERROR_THING' => 'error_thing');
function flip_and_fix( $arr ) {
   $flipped = array_flip( $arr );

   foreach ($flipped as &$f) {
     $f = "the $f return value";
   }
   unset($f);  // important to avoid issues w/ ref var
   var_dump($flipped);

}
flip_and_fix( $out );
```

see [demo](https://3v4l.org/M8Sgl)

However, the wording of the question suggests an array whose values contain function names, while each key represents a function's parameter. The challenge then is to create another array whose keys hold the function names and their corresponding values  hold the function return values, as follows:

```
<?php

function some_date($p){
     return date("j M Y",strtotime($p));
}

function error_thing($arg){
     return "$arg on line ...";
}

$out = array('now' => 'some_date', 'Parse error' => 'error_thing', 'bla' => 'blee');

function Dyn_Flip( $arr ) {
   $in = array_flip( $arr );
   foreach ($in as $k => &$v) {
         if ( function_exists($k) ) {
             $in[$k] = $k($v);
         }
         else {
             $in[$k] = "no retval -- function $k() does not exist";
         }
   }
   unset($v);
   var_dump($in);
}
Dyn_Flip( $out );
```

See [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6c99295c89584b196bf1b7ff945689da39b63661)

Comment: I'd suspect that the OP is looking to populate the array with dynamic values, not literally the string "the $f return as value".

Comment: You may be right.  If so, I think it's unclear which represents the function and which the parameter.  Also, if these are not built-in functions, then a test ought to be done to ensure that a function exists.  Thanks for offering another perspective.

Comment: Why are you doing `array_flip()`, and why pass into the `foreach` loop by reference? Good point about checking that the function exists though.

Comment: @miken32: I used array_flip() to make the function names as the array keys for convenience.  While the reference operator may seem superfluous, there might well be a performance boost to using it (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php)

Comment: There's no need (or "performance boost") to pass by reference since you aren't modifying the value. If you were really worried about pointless micro-optimization (which you should not be,) you'd not flip your array for no reason!

Comment: @miken32: thanks for your feedback.  Actually the code does change the value of the array $in and so if there's any performance gain to get, the reference operator would be helpful; see https://3v4l.org/RluO0 which demos the changed array.  I flipped the array so that the the keys are function names and the values are parameter values which seems more logical than pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since I'm not sure about the function you're running through the array; I will use `strtolower`for this example.

My example array looks like this:

`$arr = ['a' => 'AB', 'b' => 'CD'];`

I want my results in `$result`array:

`$result = array_combine($arr, array_map('strtolower', $arr));`

Let me break down this line:

```
// Run our function on the main array and change values with results
$arr1 = array_map('strtolower', $arr);

// Combine these two arrays, get keys from first and values from second
$result = array_combine($arr, $arr1);

// our new array looks as
// $result = ['AB' => 'ab', 'CD' => 'cd'];
```