# Converting Array to string and then inserting it in table td tags php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
Array ( [0] => gdhfhfh@dd.com [1] => dddgdgfdgds@ss.com [2] => s@ff.vgg [3] => safsafdsaf@fdf.dfg [4] => fghfchgfhd@fg.com [5] => owaizyusufi@gmail.com [6] => test.cc@ll.com [7] => tang.cc@dm.com )
```

I have converted it into string

```
echo  implode("<br/>",$emails);
```

but how can I insert each email_id into td tag

So it looks something like this

```
SNo. Email

1.   gdhfhfh@dd.com

2.   dddgdgfdgds@ss.com

3.  s@ff.vgg
```

Is it possible without using js

Comment: what are you talking about when you say ID tag?

Comment: @Scuzzy Update my question

Comment: Use a list... `echo '<ol><li>'.implode('</li><li>', $array).'</li></ol>';`

Comment: @dpap Sorry but if it reaches to 2000 email so its not a dynamic way

Comment: Do you really going to reach 2000 emails in a html table ?? I dont think it would be a better idea to show all the emails on one page.. rather use pagination and show fewer emails (like 100 per page).

Comment: @ezcodr Yes, I am going to have but in the future because it a company blog and I am actually featching the data from mailchimp ( as my boss has said to do it ) I will give u the link of the blog after the launch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array, loop through the array and store the parts of the array you want in a variable outside of the loop.

```
$arr = ['mail1@mail1.com', 'mail2@mail2.com'];

$html = '
    <tr>
        <td><strong>SNo.</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Email</strong></td>
    </tr>
';

if (count($arr) > 0) {
    $arrLength = count($arr);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $arrLength; $i++) {
        $html .= '
            <tr>
                <td>' . ($i+1) . '</td>
                <td>' . $arr[$i] . '</td>
            </tr>
        ';
    }
}

echo $html;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you save my day

Answer (score 2):

Simple use a list instead of `<br>`

```
echo '<tr><td>SNo. Email';
echo '<ol><li>'.implode('</li><li>', $array).'</li></ol>';
echo '</td></tr>';
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists

It will even do the numbers for you.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance also your answer is also right but I will go with andrew's answer may someone will need your answers:)

Answer (score -1):

Its better to use `foreach` loop on an array than `for` loop [know why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php) and see [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-for-and-foreach-in-php) too. This might help you.

```
$arr = ['myemail@gmail.com', 'myemail2@yahoo.com'];
    $html = '
        <tr>
            <th>SNo</td>
            <th>Email</td>
        </tr>
    ';

    if (count($arr) > 0) {
        foreach ($arr as $key=>$email) {
            $html .= '
                <tr>
                    <td>' . ($key+1) . '</td>
                    <td>' . $email . '</td>
                </tr>
            ';
        }
    }

    echo $html;
```

PHP Benchmark : [image: https://phpbench.com/]

Comment: Did a quick performance test, for vs foreach (no reference). For-loop were twice as fast as foreach in this case: https://i.gyazo.com/7991294af6c95deec9f639a265355327.png

Comment: This time difference is not that noticeable for the number of elements upto 2000. There are other reasons why you should use `foreach` instead of `for` just google it...you will find out why?

Comment: Results are the same even if we test with 1 million elements. Unless we are talking about security issues, what can be so important that you're saying `foreach` is better then `for-loop` ? After security, performance is pretty high on the list. I have been searching, and we are not talking about foreach with reference. When you claim something is better than something else here on SO you should give an explanation to why. I have given an explanation to why I disagree. Now please do the same. Benchmark: https://pastebin.com/w3avrkEH

Comment: Yes, we are not talking about security and neither the performance is a big concern in the original question. YES! I would still say its better to use `foreach` than `for` in simple setuations like this, the reason why is, using `for` or `while` is so old school and most importantly when performance is not a big concern. And do you totly agree with the results of benchmark you have attached ?? check this link https://phpbench.com/ too.
I have referenced why I would use `foreach` instead of `for` in this setuation in my edited answer.

Comment: I have read the codes at phpbench.com as you can see they can't be compared to our scenario at all. In their first `for-loop` benchmark they're using `array_keys` which returns an array which is not necessary at all as you can use the counter in a `for-loop`. You have linked to a benchmark, where the user writing the tests have not selected the most efficient way for a normal array. Read his test code and you'll see. There is nothing wrong in using `foreach` in this scenario. But it's wrong to say that it's better than a for-loop when you can't provide proper documentation confirming this.

Comment: Also I have to add that the only reason the tests you linked til shows that `foreach` is faster is because they are supporting "HashMap's" (arrays with non/unordered numeric keys) which is not the case in this thread. Here we are talking about a normal array, starting with a index at 0, which increases by 1 for each added element.