# Adding one character to each array key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest way to add prefix to array keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607595/fastest-way-to-add-prefix-to-array-keys)

I had a quick question about arrays in PHP. I need to add a couple of characters to each key in an array, for instance:

> name => Mark age => 23 weight = > 150

needs to be converted to:

> r_name => Mark r_age => 23 r_weight =>
>   150

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: duplicate of a lot of posts, in fact

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Iterate the array, add a new item with the modified key and delete the original item:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    $arr['r_'.$key] = $val;
    unset($arr[$key]);
}
```

As `foreach` works with an internal copy of the array, you won’t run into an infinite loop.

Comment: "As foreach works with an internal copy of the array, you won’t run into an infinite loop"... Good point!

Comment: Whoa, didn't know of that internal copy thing. Up for that!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post: [In PHP, how do you change the key of an array element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element)

Answer (score 1):

If you can be sure, that there are no two keys $K1,$K2 in your array with $K1 = "r_".$K2 , you can use the solution given by Gumbo - its efficient and nice.

If you can not guarantee the stated condition, i would prefer generating a new array with the altered keys and deleting/overwriting the old one afterwards.
This is not as memory efficient as the other solution but wont fail.

Another thing to keep in mind is, that unset is a bit slow in PHP. So Unsetting a lot of elements in your array might be slower than working with a copy and deleting the original afterwards.