# Prefixing array keys with a string (:) in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, key

Quick one; I know a solution, but I'm looking for something more elegant if it exists.

I'm using PDO for prepeared statements:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (foo, bar, baz) VALUES (:foo, :bar, :baz)";

$source->execute($sql, array(
    ':foo' => $foo,
    ':bar' => $bar,
    ':baz' => $baz,
));
```

This is fine, but I want to pass in a previously created array, however the keys contained aren't prefixed by the colon (`:`), and I figure there must be an elegant way to take:

```
$array = array(
    'foo' => 'some',
    'bar' => 'random',
    'baz' => 'value',
);
```

And translate it into:

```
$array = array(
    ':foo' => 'some',
    ':bar' => 'random',
    ':baz' => 'value',
);
```

Without doing:

```
$temp = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $temp[':' . $key] = $value;
}
$array = $temp;
```

I've browsed the PHP docs, but I can't find a function (*or sequence of*) that suits the purpose.

Any ideas?

---

### Addendum

Leaving the accepted answer, but +1 @chim for his clever 1-liner; solves the X in my XY problem. Reformatted solution:

```
$format = ':%s';
$values = array_flip(array_map(function ($key) use($format) {
    return sprintf($format, $key);
}, array_flip($values)));
```

Wrapped in a function, perhaps `array_keys_format(array $array, $format)`

Comment: AFAIK PDO's `execute()` will work correctly even if the keys aren't prefixed by a colon.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607595/fastest-way-to-add-prefix-to-array-keys

Comment: @NullUserException - I thought that too, but its kicking back invalid SQL state, complaining about the query parameters (*other than the colon prefix, it would run given its unnecessary*)

Comment: @Bracketworks: what php version are you using? Tested with `5.2.17` and `5.3.8` here, and working as expected.

Comment: @fireeyedboy - Yea, sleep deprivation != working. `5.3.6`, and yea, its working :) Sorry NullUser, you were right also.

Comment: @Dan to be fair, double flipping is not a safe technique.  Values that are deemed "duplicated" upon becoming keys will result in corrupted payloads.  Chim's approach is not suitable for general use.  [I recommend `substr_replace()` on the keys and then `array_combine()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76196482/2943403)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$source->execute($sql, array(
    'foo' => $foo,
    'bar' => $bar,
    'baz' => $baz
));
```

This is presuming the above calls `PDOStatement::execute()` under the hood, with the above `array` as its argument.<sup>1</sup>

**:)**

---

<sup>1) Tested with version `5.2.17` and `5.3.8` here, and working as expected.</sup>

Comment: You know, perhaps it's late, but its working now. I'm going to bed, but first I'm accepting this answer because it fixes the problem, just as NullUser had said too. +1's all around. Thanks @fireeyedboy!

Answer (score 3):

It has already been answered but this is what I came up with anyway.

```
$arr = array('foo'=>1,'bar'=>2);

$arr = array_flip($arr);

array_walk($arr,create_function('&$v,$k', '$v = ":$v";'));

$arr = array_flip($arr);

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

use the php map-function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

```
function reduce($key)
{
if(strpos($key,":")===0)
return substr($key,1);
return $key;
}

$array = array_map("reduce",$array);
```

Comment: Doesn't work array_map doesn't affect the keys of an array, and the reduce function above doesn't prepend a : to the beginning of anything.

Comment: What the function does do is remove a leading : from the values in the array.

Answer (score 2):

One liner...

```
$array = array('test'=>'55','yest'=>'66');

$array = array_flip(array_map(function($v){return ':' . $v;},array_flip($array)));

// array(':test'=>'55',':yest'=>'66');
```

However this isn't safe as array_flip relies on all values being unique.

So one of the looping solutions is probably the best, or alternatively array_keys with array_combine.

Comment: Flipping must not be trusted if the values in the array may collide after being coalesced to a scalar-type key.