# PHP Inserting array values into MySQL prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have an array of values that I am trying to insert into a database.  Currently the below only inserts the first key value pair in the array and then returns an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General       error' in /_/components/php/functions.php:33
Stack trace:
0 /_/components/php/functions.php(33): PDOStatement->fetchAll()
1 /testdb.php(44): Photo\DB\query('INSERT into cat...', Array, Object(PDO))
2 {main} thrown in /_/components/php/functions.php on line 33
```

line 33 in functions.php is in this function

```
function query($query, $bindings, $conn){
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($bindings);
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();  <---line 33

    return $results ? $results : false;
}
```

The main code is

```
foreach ($sitecategories as $key => $value) {
    // print "this is key $key and this is value $value";
    if ( $conn ) {
        $catquery=query("INSERT into categories (cat_id, label) VALUES (:catid, :label)",
        array('catid'=>$key, 'label'=>$value), 
        $conn);
    } else {
        print "could not connect to the database";
    }
}
```

So I am connecting OK to the DB (elsewhere in the code) and the first key value pair is inserted successfully but not the rest of the array.  I'm guessing my syntax is incorrect somewhere in

```
array('catid'=>$key, 'label'=>$value),
```

but I can't figure it out.  Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't `fetchAll()` after you `INSERT`.  `INSERT` has no result set.

I just ran a test of inserting and then calling `fetchAll()` on the PDOStatement object, and I confirm that this causes the "General error" exception you showed.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into foo () values ()");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Throws:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 
'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error' in /Users/billkarwin/workspace/PHP/21194489.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/billkarwin/workspace/PHP/21194489.php(14): PDOStatement->fetchAll()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Users/billkarwin/workspace/PHP/21194489.php on line 14
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array of values is incorrect.  The keys need to have the `:`, too.

```
array(':catid'=>$key, ':label'=>$value)
```

Comment: Not bad for a guy who's only studied this type of coding for a week or so. `$guy="me";` ;-)

Comment: This was true in older versions of PDO, but not anymore. The keys don't need the `:` prefix. This makes it a lot easier to pass the `$_POST` array as your query parameters without having to change the keys.

Comment: @BillKarwin: [citation needed]

Comment: Why, because of people constantly forgetting to put them? @BillKarwin lol

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619053/prefixing-array-keys-with-a-string-in-php

Comment: @BillKarwin: Hmm, interesting.  Thanks! :-)

Comment: @BillKarwin Nice note on the bug fix. Having to add the `:` always seemed like a very odd design decision.