# Read external variable with create_function php

Tags: php, arrays, array-map, create-function

I need to append a prefix to each key in my array. The prefix it is defined outside the create_function I am using. How can I make it accessible from inside?

Here my code ($result is my array of key => value):

```
$groupName = $reader->getAttribute('name');

$resultKeyPrefixGroup = array_combine(
                    array_map(create_function('$k', 'return $groupName."/".$k;'), array_keys($result)),
                    $result
                );
```

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to add prefix to array keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607595/fastest-way-to-add-prefix-to-array-keys)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7619053/2943403

Answer (score 1):

This hurt my brain wrapping my head around escaping the string:

```
<?php
$result = 
[
    '1' => 'One',
    '2' => 'Two'
];

$groupName = 'braves';

$resultKeyPrefixGroup = array_combine(
    array_map(
        create_function('$k', "return '$groupName/'.\$k;"),
        array_keys($result)
    ),
    $result
);
var_export($resultKeyPrefixGroup);
```

Output:

```
array (
    'braves/1' => 'One',
    'braves/2' => 'Two',
)
```

As create_function is deprecated as of 7.2.0 I'd recommend one of my alternative approaches.

Comment: This `"return '$groupName/'".'.$k;'` or `"return '$groupName/'.\$k;"` any better? Nice logic puzzle.

Comment: @Xorifelse, that's much better.  I obviously didn't break my brain enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an anonymous function:

```
<?php
$result = 
[
    '1' => 'One',
    '2' => 'Two'
];

$prefix = 'pink/';
$prefix_key = function($str) use ($prefix) {
    return $prefix . $str;
};

$prefixed = array_combine(
    array_map($prefix_key, array_keys($result)),
    $result
);

var_export($prefixed);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'pink/1' => 'One',
  'pink/2' => 'Two',
)
```

Though it might be just as well to loop and build your new array:

```
foreach($result as $k => $v)
    $prefixed["pink/$k"] = $v;
```