# PHP associative key array vs number key array

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest way to add prefix to array keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607595/fastest-way-to-add-prefix-to-array-keys)

I have an array that does like this:

```
0 => value 1,
1 => value 2,
```

I want to done like this:

```
keyname1 => value 1,
keyname2 => value 2,
```

In the mySQL database, all the columns have names but the array is using numbers instead of names.  Is there a PHP or mySQL command that tells it how to write the keys?

Comment: If the data is coming from mySQL, have you tried fetching the data _as an associative array_? `$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`, in case you're using PDO, that fetches the first result of the query as an associative array

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted.  Post answer, please.

Comment: @Plummer, posted answer, I don't know if you're using PDO or not, but I hope/assume you do. I just added the deprecated thing for anybody who might stumble on this question later.

Comment: @Elias, I'm actually using Joomla, but using your answer, I was able to translate into Joomla speak and find the answer I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your comment:

You're retrieving data from a mySQL database, so you can just fetch the data as an associative array:

*PDO:*

```
//just as an example
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT foo, bar from foobar.foobaz WHERE xyz = :xyz');
$stmt->execute(array(':xyz' => $someValue));
$results = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    array_push($results, $row);
}
```

That should do it. Of course, there is `mysql_fetch_assoc`, but since the `mysql_*` extension is deprecated, I'm not going to bother with that, just switch to PDO, if you haven't already.

If you're not comfortable with PDO for some reason, look into `mysqli_*`, in which case the loop looks like this:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc())
{//using OO api
    array_push($results, $row);
}
//or
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{//using OO api
    array_push($results, $row);
}
```

full examples [on the doc pages](http://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc

Answer (score 1):

```
array_walk($array, function($value, &$key){ $key = 'prefix' . $key;});
```

Answer (score 1):

After fetching the resultset, traverse it with a loop, and add the column names as `keys` to the array. here's an example,

```
foreach($resultset as $k => $v)
 $array[$k] = $v;
```

I am assuming that `$resultset` is an array.

**Note:** Mysql_* extensions are deprecated. Try to use Mysqli_* or PDO extensions instead.

Comment: Yes.  And just to be clear, instead of the array printing the index number, I want the column name. So where it would be <table><th><td>Name</td><td>Age</td></th><tr><td>John</td><td>42</td></tr></table>, I want it to print `name => john, age => 42` (sorry, html table didn't come out right in comments)

Comment: First of all, the table you mentioned in the comment, is HTML table and `NOT Mysql table`. Secondly, do you want an array with keys `name` and `age` or do you want to literally print something like `name => john, age => 42` ?

Comment: Show the code where you fetch the resultset. I can guide you from there.

Comment: HTML was just for example.  I was hoping it would just show an table and not a bunch of markup.  I want the array to look like `array ( name => john, age => 42)` from which I can pull data into something else.

Comment: okies gotcha...then my initial answer should work for you.