# how to inject variable into another variable of value

Tags: php

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$Formula = $data->Formula; //getting value ($N-$D)*100.
$N = $data->Numerator; //getting value 100
$D = $data->Denominator; //getting value 20
```

I am getting JSON values like the above way. I want to inject $N,$D values to the variable of $Formula value. I want Output like below : (100-20)*100 = 8000

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to add an example of the `$data`?

Comment: You will need to use `eval()`.

Comment: However, this is very dangerous to do with user-supplied data, since it will execute any PHP functions. You really should find some other way to accomplish this that doesn't require evaluating user-supplied formulas.

Comment: i tried eval(). eval("\$Formula = \"$Formula\";");  it combines the values. but i need calculated value that is 8000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all;

> **Caution**
>
> The eval() language construct is ***very dangerous*** because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code.

---

Sharing my solution, using:

1. `array_combine`, `array_map` and `array_keys` to prefix all the keys with an `$`

   <sup>[Fastest way to add prefix to array keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607595/fastest-way-to-add-prefix-to-array-keys)</sup>
   <sup>Keep in mind that this expects a formula were all the variables exist in `$data`</sup>
2. [`strtr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) to replace `$N` with `$data->N`
3. [`eval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) to calculate the string: [calculate math expression from a string using eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880772/calculate-math-expression-from-a-string-using-eval)

Code:

```php
<?php

// Original data
$data = (Object) [
    'formula'   => '($N-$D)*100',
    'N'         => 100,
    'D'         => 20
];

// Create an object were 'N => 100' is saved as '$N => 100'
$ovars = get_object_vars($data);
$ovars = array_combine(array_map(function($k){ return '$' . $k; }, array_keys($ovars)), $ovars);

// Replace (oa) $N with $ovars['$N']
$sum = strtr($data->formula, $ovars);

// EVAL
$res = eval('return ' . $sum . ';');

// Show result
echo "SUM: $sum\nRESULT: $res";
```

Result:

```
SUM: (100-20)*100
RESULT: 8000
```