# Use flat array's values to generate an associative array whose keys and values are given a static prefix

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, array-map, array-combine

Is there a shorthand for the following code:

```php
$result = array_combine(
    array_map(fn($elem) => "key_$elem", $array), 
    array_map(fn($elem) => "value_$elem", $array)
);
```

[PHP Sandbox](https://onlinephp.io/c/850d6)

I do not like the idea (from readability point of view) of having to use array map twice on the same array and then combining the intermediate results.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a brand new techique which outperforms all previously posted techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update 2024-03-08:

To my surprise, `substr_replace()` calls inside of `array_combine()` ([solitary demo](https://3v4l.org/lQoL6)) outperforms `foreach()` frequently enough to consider it "the best" in my eyes. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ri89S))

```
function substrReplaceCombine($array) {
    return array_combine(
        substr_replace($array, 'key', 0, 0),
        substr_replace($array, 'value', 0, 0)
    );
}
```

Output for 8.3.4 (hand sorted ASC)

```
Duration of substrReplaceCombine: 0.71814060211182
Duration of reduce:               0.93705654144287
Duration of construct:            0.95775127410889
Duration of mapCombine:           1.0146498680115
Duration of mapFlatten:           1.1467099189758
Duration of mapUncolumn:          1.1523962020874
Duration of walk:                 1.2235164642334
Duration of generator:            1.5499591827393
```

---

Original answer:

I find this contrived task to be rather unrealistic (unfathomable as a real word use case).  The preference of code styling is going to come down to personal preference.

If we are going to consider options from an academic vector, then we should not only compare code brevity, but also time complexity, directness, minimizing function calls, and perhaps even memory.

TL;DR:

1. Classic language construct iteration (like `foreach()`) will consistently outperform functional iterators.  Using generators means a trade off of performance for memory savings.
2. All other functional iterators are near enough in there execution time that you probably shouldn't waste development time thinking about which one is fastest.
3. Of all of the approaches that I tested, only `array_reduce()` encountered a catastrophic memory problem. After researching, I found that [using an ArrayObject](https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/8283) will overcome the under-the-hood memory challenges (for when you cannot simply increase the memory allowance).

---

Now I will list the different approaches pulled from [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76196482/2943403) to a VERY similar question which I tweaked and extended with a few more approaches.

- Generator with `foreach()`

  ```
  function generate($array) {  // 1 loop over data
      foreach ($array as $v) {
          yield 'key' . $v => 'value' . $v;
      }
  }

  function generator($array) {  // 1 parent loop over data
      return iterator_to_array(generate($array));
  }
  ```
- An ordinary `foreach()` loop:

  ```
  function construct($array) {  // 1 loop over data
      $result = [];
      foreach ($array as $v) {
          $result['key' . $v] = 'value' . $v;
      }
      return $result;
  }
  ```
- `array_combine()` with two nested `array_map()` calls:

  ```
  function mapCombine($array) {  // 3 loops over data
      return array_combine(
                 array_map(
                     fn($v) => 'key' . $v,
                     $array
                 ),
                 array_map(
                     fn($v) => 'value' . $v,
                     $array
                 ),
             );
  }
  ```
- Flattening an 2d array:

  ```
  function mapFlatten($array) {  // 3 loops over data
      return array_merge(
                 ...array_map(
                     fn($v) => ['key' . $v => 'value' . $v],
                     $array
                 ),
             );
  }
  ```
- Convert a 2d array into an associative with `array_column()`:

  ```
  function mapUncolumn($array) {  // 2 loops over data
      return array_column(
                 array_map(
                     fn($v) => ['key' . $v, 'value' . $v],
                     $array
                 ),
                 1,
                 0
             );
  }
  ```
- `array_walk()` with reference array:

  ```
  function walk($array) {  // 1 loop over data
      $result = [];
      array_walk(
          $array,
          function($v) use (&$result) {
              $result['key' . $v] = 'value' . $v;
          }
      );
      return $result;
  }
  ```
- `array_reduce()` built to handle large payloads:

  ```
  function reduce($array) {  // 1 loop over data
      return array_reduce(
                 $array,
                 function($result, $v) {
                     $result['key' . $v] = 'value' . $v;
                     return $result;
                 },
                 new ArrayObject()
             );
  }
  ```

My testing script: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/57SrG))

```
function returnTime(callable $function, int $repeat = 20)
{
    $tests = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $repeat; ++$i) {
        $startTime = microtime(true);
        $function();
        $endTime = microtime(true);
        $tests[] = $endTime - $startTime;
    }
    // Representing the average
    return 1000 * array_sum($tests) / $repeat;
}

$array = range(0, 5000);

foreach (['generator', 'construct', 'mapCombine', 'mapFlatten', 'mapUncolumn', 'walk', 'reduce'] as $test) {
    echo "Duration of $test: ", returnTime(fn() => $test($array)) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Results for PHP8.3.4 (sorted by speed):

```
Duration of construct:   0.72321891784668
Duration of reduce:      0.91509819030762
Duration of mapCombine:  0.94027519226074
Duration of mapFlatten:  1.1523604393005
Duration of walk:        1.1601090431213
Duration of mapUncolumn: 1.163923740387
Duration of generator:   1.2189626693726
```

Results for PHP8.3.3 (sorted by speed):

```
Duration of construct:   0.68153142929077
Duration of reduce:      0.91077089309692
Duration of generator:   0.93502998352051
Duration of mapCombine:  0.94808340072632
Duration of mapFlatten:  1.1013269424438
Duration of walk:        1.132333278656
Duration of mapUncolumn: 1.1387705802917
```

---

If I was to need such a process to be executed in a professional application, I'd probably use @User863's snippet -- it is clean, direct, functional-style, and doesn't bother making more than one iteration.

Note that I was not able to use the union operator `+` in my `array_reduce()` script because it doesn't work with ArrayObject type data.

If I had performance concerns, I'd use a foreach.

If I had memory concerns, I'd use a generator.

Comment: it looks like you're testing `generate` function, which is basically single op, I'd say you need to test `generator` - which actually creates array

Comment: GASP, you are right! Thanks for catching that.  I've updated my tests, results, and answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_reduce`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

```php
$result = array_reduce($array, fn ($carry, $item) => $carry + ["key_$item" => "value_$item"], []);
```

[PHP Sandbox](https://onlinephp.io/c/d99ad)

Answer (score 1):

I'd just define simple function, like that:

```
function array2map($a) {
    $r = []; foreach ($a as $v) $r['key_'.$v] = 'value_'.$v; return $r;
}

$result = array2map($array);
```

Comment: The style of just putting loads of statements on one line goes against most coding standards I've ever seen.

Comment: @NigelRen and yet it is shorter, readable, easier to comprehend, and faster than either variant with array_combine/array_reduce :)

Comment: That is also an opinion which isn't always the best indication of what is 'better'. Although the approach is good - it's not just about being shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. However, I have reached a solution that I like more:

```php
$result = array_merge(...array_map(fn($elem) => ["key_$elem" => "value_$elem"], $array));
```

[PHP Sandbox](https://onlinephp.io/c/5699b)

Comment: just wondering what you like about it, because from performance point of view it makes 2 times more work than needed, uses twice memory, and logically harder to understand because instead of straightforward array->map it performs array->many arrays->map

Comment: What I like more about is that it looks cleaner. I do not know much about performance and memory - I am a newbie when it comes to programming. Is it really that bad? To me, it seems like it does as many operations and uses as much memory as the array_reduce suggestion - I have the impression that array_merge is a specific case of array_reduce.